# Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C?

Tags: c, performance, oop, post-increment, pre-increment

Is there a performance difference between `i++` and `++i` if the resulting value is not used?

Comment: Related, the same question but explicitly for C++ is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Answer (score 461, accepted):

Executive summary:  No.

`i++` could potentially be slower than `++i`, since the old value of `i`
might need to be saved for later use, but in practice all modern
compilers will optimize this away.

We can demonstrate this by looking at the code for this function,
both with `++i` and `i++`.

```
$ cat i++.c
extern void g(int i);
void f()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        g(i);

}
```

The files are the same, except for `++i` and `i++`:

```
$ diff i++.c ++i.c
6c6
<     for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
---
>     for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
```

We'll compile them, and also get the generated assembler:

```bash
$ gcc -c i++.c ++i.c
$ gcc -S i++.c ++i.c
```

And we can see that both the generated object and assembler files are the same.

```
$ md5 i++.s ++i.s
MD5 (i++.s) = 90f620dda862cd0205cd5db1f2c8c06e
MD5 (++i.s) = 90f620dda862cd0205cd5db1f2c8c06e

$ md5 *.o
MD5 (++i.o) = dd3ef1408d3a9e4287facccec53f7d22
MD5 (i++.o) = dd3ef1408d3a9e4287facccec53f7d22
```

Comment: I know this question is about C, but I'd be interested to know if browsers can do this optimization for javascript.

Comment: Even if the compiler didn't optimize you'd be very unlikely to notice the difference on any modern CPU.

Comment: So the "No" is true for the one compiler you tested with.

Comment: @Andreas: Good question. I used to be a compiler writer, and had the opportunity to test this code on many CPUs, operating systems, and compilers.  The only compiler I found  that didn't optimize the i++ case (in fact, the compiler that brought this to my attention professionally) was the Software Toolworks C80 compiler by Walt Bilofsky.  That compiler was for Intel 8080 CP/M systems.  It's safe to say that any compiler which does not include this optimization is not one meant for general use.

Comment: Also, the `no` is only tested for integers, however, the question does not mention the type of `i`. Then your generalisation in line 1. Sorry, -1.

Comment: Even though the performance difference is negligible, and optimized out in many cases - please take note that it's still good practice to use `++i` instead of `i++`. There's absolutely no reason not to, and if your software ever passes through a toolchain that doesn't optimize it out your software will be more efficient.

Considering it is just as easy to type `++i` as it is to type `i++`, there is really no excuse to not be using `++i` in the first place.

Comment: @Andreas: Most compilers do optimize this. It would make no sense for a compiler to use i++ when you aren't using it's return value anywhere. However, that same logic should also propagate all the way down to the programmer.

Relying on optimizations is a problem by itself.

Comment: @monokrome As developers can provide their own implementation for the prefix and postfix operators in many languages, this may not always be an acceptable solution for a compiler to make without first comparing those functions, which may be non-trivial.

Comment: @pickypg, good point about the differences in languages. monokrome's advice is sound for C, which is what this particular question addresses.

Comment: @MarkHarrison Agreed. I just found my way here from a different question and didn't want people reading through this with the assumption that might be raised based on the very first question in this comment thread.

Comment: @pickypg Please pay attention to the questions here. This question is about C, so your point is not valid in context of the discussion here.

One great thing about C is that it does not support operator overloading.

Comment: Of course I believe that for any non-crappy C compiler the answer is No. But in since many programmers who do C programming also do C++ programming, using ++i by default is preferred. Just a good habit to keep, even if it's pointless in C.

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04 64bits, the *.o files (resp. *.s files) checksums are different, even if we force optimization with -O3 option. Of course, this does not prove that the same assembly codes are different.

Comment: It's still called an optimization. For some reason it is done even with zero optimization flags, but it's definitely not the same as implementing out a statement that does nothing (e.g. `i;`) since the underlying code "should" at least copy a register when using the postfix operator.

Comment: @monokrome very good points and I agree with them. Especially about how that logic should propagate down to the programmer. Another reason why `++i` should be the go-to default is because it's easier to see that something is being incremented. Take `reallylongvariablename++;` for instance vs. `++reallylongvariablename;`. It's much easier to see that the first one is being incremented (e.g. like when it's on a line by itself). And is more in line with how you read it in your mind, "increment i" -> "++i".

Comment: I repeated the above scenario with a loop using `size_t` and my hashes are different. Running g++ 5.3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @StevenWalton diff the .s files and see where they differ

Comment: `diff i++.s ++i.s` shows just the filename and a 1c1 at the top. Diffing the cpp files just shows the difference in i++ and ++i. I did a small test and found that the ++i was a little faster. But the total run time was about 3 seconds. After 10 runs each ++i was avg 3.3153 and i++ was avg 3.3248. Saw this same relative difference when moved loops to ~30sec. Not a big difference at all.

Comment: Beware that md5 is prone to collisions    :)

Answer (score 131):

From [Efficiency versus intent](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/efficiency-versus-intent/228700184) by Andrew Koenig :

> First, it is far from obvious that `++i` is more efficient than `i++`, at least where integer variables are concerned.

And :

> So the question one should be asking is not which of these two operations is faster, it is which of these two operations expresses more accurately what you are trying to accomplish.  I submit that if you are not using the value of the expression, there is never a reason to use `i++` instead of `++i`, because there is never a reason to copy the value of a variable, increment the variable, and then throw the copy away.

So, if the resulting value is not used, I would use `++i`. But not because it is more efficient: because it correctly states my intent.

Comment: Let's not forget that other unary operators are prefix as well.  I think ++i  is the "semantic" way to use a unary operator, while i++ is around in order to fit a specific need (evaluation before addition).

Comment: If the resulting value is not used, there's *no difference* in semantics: i.e., there is no basis for prefering one or the other construct.

Comment: As a reader, I see a difference. So as a writer, I'll show my intent by choosing one over the other. It's just a habit I have, to try to communicate with my programmer friends and teammates through code :)

Comment: Why would `i++` create a copy instead of simply postponing the increment until after the expression referencing the variable is completed? Were older compilers not smart enough to do that?

Comment: It is easy to create reasons when it doesn't make much difference, it's bike shedding, essentially. I'm sure someone could argue that i++ is preferable because ++i looks to similar to +i, and for beginners, ++i might get only a weird look but i++ will get them to open the chapters about operators.

Comment: Following Koenig's advice, I code `i++` the same way I'd code `i += n` or `i = i + n`, i.e., in the form *target* *verb* *object*, with the *target* operand to the left of the *verb* operator. In the case of `i++`, there is no right *object*, but the rule still applies, keeping the *target* to the left of the *verb* operator.

Comment: If you are trying to increment i, then i++ and ++i both correctly express your intent.  There is no reason to prefer one over the other.    As a reader i see no difference, do your colleagues get confused when they see i++ and think, maybe this is a typo and he didn't mean to increment i?

Comment: There is a difference. Consider this:

1) int i = 0;
2) int x = i++;
3) int y = ++i;

Reading this semantically, line 2 says: "Give me the value of i, then increment it."; whereas line 3 says "Increment i, then give me its value."

Comment: @Ifalin, We're talking about standalones. No one in the right mind uses `i++` / `++i` as part of a statement.

Comment: If you are trying to "increment i" it is far more natural to read "increment i" than to read "i increment". So even ignoring compiler optimization. It's optimizing readability.

Answer (score 54):

A better answer is that `++i` will sometimes be faster but never slower.

Everyone seems to be assuming that `i` is a regular built-in type such as `int`. In this case there will be no measurable difference.

However if `i` is  complex type then you may well find a measurable difference. For `i++` you must make a copy of your class before incrementing it. Depending on what's involved in a copy it could indeed be slower since with `++i` you can just return the final value.

```
Foo Foo::operator++()
{
  Foo oldFoo = *this; // copy existing value - could be slow
  // yadda yadda, do increment
  return oldFoo;
}
```

Another difference is that with `++i` you have the option of returning a reference instead of a value. Again, depending on what's involved in making a copy of your object this could be slower.

A real-world example of where this can occur would be the use of iterators. Copying an iterator is unlikely to be a bottle-neck in your application, but it's still good practice to get into the habit of using `++i` instead of `i++` where the outcome is not affected.

Comment: The question explicitly states C, no reference to C++.

Comment: This (admittedly old) question was about C, not C++, but I figure it's also worth mentioning that, in C++, even if a class implements post- and pre-fix operators, they're not even necessarily related. For example bar++ may increment one data member, while ++bar may increment a different data member, and in this case, you wouldn't have the option to use either, as the semantics are different.

Comment: -1 While this is good advise for C++ programmers, it doesn't answer the question, which is tagged C, in the slightest. In C, it absolutely makes no difference whether you use prefix or postfix.

Comment: @Pacerier The question is tagged C, and C only. Why do you assume they are not interested in that? Given how SO works, wouldn't it rather be smart to assume they are _only_ interested in C, rather than Java, C#, COBOL or any other off-topic language?

Answer (score 23):

*Short answer:*

There is never any difference between `i++` and `++i` in terms of speed. A good compiler should not generate different code in the two cases.

*Long answer:*

What every other answer fails to mention is that the difference between `++i` versus `i++` only makes sense within the expression it is found.

In the case of `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`, the `i++` is alone in its own expression: there is a sequence point before the `i++` and there is one after it. Thus the only machine code generated is "increase `i` by `1`" and it is well-defined how this is sequenced in relation to the rest of the program. So if you would change it to prefix `++`, it wouldn't matter in the slightest, you would still just get the machine code "increase `i` by `1`".

The differences between `++i` and `i++` only matters in expressions such as `array[i++] = x;` versus `array[++i] = x;`. Some may argue and say that the postfix will be slower in such operations because the register where `i` resides has to be reloaded later. But then note that the compiler is free to order your instructions in any way it pleases, as long as it doesn't "break the behavior of the abstract machine" as the C standard calls it.

So while you may assume that `array[i++] = x;` gets translated to machine code as:

- Store value of `i` in register A.
- Store address of array in register B.
- Add A and B, store results in A.
- At this new address represented by A, store the value of x.
- Store value of `i` in register A   // inefficient because extra instruction here, we already did this once.
- Increment register A.
- Store register A in `i`.

the compiler might as well produce the code more efficiently, such as:

- Store value of `i` in register A.
- Store address of array in register B.
- Add A and B, store results in B.
- Increment register A.
- Store register A in `i`.
- ... // rest of the code.

Just because you as a C programmer is trained to think that the postfix `++` happens at the end, the machine code doesn't have to be ordered in that way.

So there is no difference between prefix and postfix `++` in C. Now what you as a C programmer should be vary of, is people who inconsistently use prefix in some cases and postfix in other cases, without any rationale why. This suggests that they are uncertain about how C works or that they have incorrect knowledge of the language. This is always a bad sign, it does in turn suggest that they are making other questionable decisions in their program, based on superstition or "religious dogmas".

"Prefix `++` is always faster" is indeed one such false dogma that is common among would-be C programmers.

Comment: No one said "Prefix ++ is always faster". That's misquoted. What they said was "Postfix ++ is **never** faster".

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not quoting any particular person, but just a wide-spread, incorrect belief.

Comment: @rbaleksandar c++ == c && ++c != c

Answer (score 20):

Taking a leaf from Scott Meyers, [More Effective c++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X) *Item 6: Distinguish between prefix and postfix forms of increment and decrement operations*.

The prefix version is always preferred over the postfix in regards to objects, especially in regards to iterators.

The reason for this if you look at the call pattern of the operators.

```
// Prefix
Integer& Integer::operator++()
{
    *this += 1;
    return *this;
}

// Postfix
const Integer Integer::operator++(int)
{
    Integer oldValue = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return oldValue;
}
```

Looking at this example it is easy to see how the prefix operator will always be more efficient than the postfix. Because of the need for a temporary object in the use of the postfix.

This is why when you see examples using iterators they always use the prefix version.

But as you point out for int's there is effectively no difference because of compiler optimisation that can take place.

Comment: I think his question was directed at C, but for C++ you're absolutely right, and furthermore C people should adopt this as they can use it for C++ as well. I far too often see C programmers use the postfix syntax ;-)

Comment: -1 While this is good advise for C++ programmers, it doesn't answer the question, which is tagged C, in the slightest. In C, it absolutely makes no difference whether you use prefix or postfix.

Comment: @Lundin prefix and postifx do matter in C as per the answer by [Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/528667/1675). You cannot assume that the compiler will optimize away, and it is just good practise for any language to **Alwas prefer ++i over i++**

Comment: @JProgrammer They don't matter as per the answer by yours sincerely :) If you find that they do yield different code, that is either because you failed to enable optimizations, or because the compiler is bad. Anyway, your answer is off-topic as the question was about C.

Answer (score 20):

First of all: The difference between `i++` and `++i` is neglegible in C.

---

To the details.

#### 1. The well known C++ issue: `++i` is faster

In C++, `++i` is more efficient iff `i` is some kind of an object with an overloaded increment operator.

Why?
In `++i`, the object is first incremented, and can subsequently passed as a const reference to any other function. This is not possible if the expression is `foo(i++)` because now the increment needs to be done before `foo()` is called, but the old value needs to be passed to `foo()`. Consequently, the compiler is forced to make a copy of `i` before it executes the increment operator on the original. The additional constructor/destructor calls are the bad part.

As noted above, this does not apply to fundamental types.

#### 2. The little known fact: `i++` *may* be faster

If no constructor/destructor needs to be called, which is always the case in C, `++i` and `i++` should be equally fast, right? No. They are virtually equally fast, but there may be small differences, which most other answerers got the wrong way around.

How can `i++` be faster?
The point is data dependencies. If the value needs to be loaded from memory, two subsequent operations need to be done with it, incrementing it, and using it. With `++i`, the incrementation needs to be done *before* the value can be used. With `i++`, the use does not depend on the increment, and the CPU may perform the use operation *in parallel* to the increment operation. The difference is at most one CPU cycle, so it is really neglegible, but it is there. And it is the other way round then many would expect.

Comment: About your point 2: If the `++i` or `i++` is used within another expression, changing between them changes semantics of the expression, so any possible performance gain/loss is out of question. If they are standalone, i.e., the result of the operation is not used immediately, then any decent compiler would compile it to the same thing, for example an `INC` assembly instruction.

Comment: @Shahbaz That's perfectly true, but not the point. 1) Even though the semantics are different, both `i++` and `++i` can be used interchangeably in almost every possible situation by adjusting loop constants by one, so they are near equivalent in what they do for the programmer. 2) Even though both compile to the same instruction, their execution differs for the CPU. In the case of `i++`, the CPU can compute the increment *in parallel* to some other instruction that uses the same value (CPUs really do this!), while with `++i` the CPU has to schedule the other instruction *after* the increment.

Comment: @Shahbaz As an example: `if(++foo == 7) bar();` and `if(foo++ == 6) bar();` are functionally equivalent. However, the second may be one cycle faster, because the compare and the increment can be computed in parallel by the CPU. Not that this single cycle matters much, but the difference is there.

Comment: Good point. Constants show up a lot (as well as `<` for example vs `<=`) where `++` is usually used, so the conversion between the though is often easily possible.

Comment: I like point 2, but that applies only if the value is used, righ? The question says "if the resulting value is not used?", so it can be confusing.

Comment: @jinawee If the value of `++i` or `i++` is not used, the two are fully equivalent, and should compile to exactly the same code. (Unless `i` is an object of a class that has non-standard, distinct pre/post increment operators).

Answer (score 19):

Here's an additional observation if you're worried about micro optimisation. Decrementing loops can 'possibly' be more efficient than incrementing loops (depending on instruction set architecture e.g. ARM), given:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

On each loop you you will have one instruction each for:

1. Adding `1` to `i`.
2. Compare whether `i` is less than a `100`.
3. A conditional branch if `i` is less than a `100`.

Whereas a decrementing loop:

```
for (i = 100; i != 0; i--)
```

The loop will have an instruction for each of:

1. Decrement `i`, setting the CPU register status flag.
2. A conditional branch depending on CPU register status (`Z==0`).

Of course this works only when decrementing to zero!

Remembered from the ARM System Developer's Guide.

Comment: Good one. But doesn't this create fewer cache hits?

Comment: There is an old weird trick from code optimization books, combining advantage of zero-test branch with incremented address. Here's example in high level language(probably useless, since many compilers are smart enough to replace it with _less_ efficient but more common loop code):


int a[N];
for( i = -N; i ; ++i) a[N+i] += 123;

Comment: @noop could you possibly elaborate on which code optimization books you refer to? I have struggled to find good ones.

Comment: This answer isn't an answer to the question at all.

Comment: @mezamorphic For x86 my sources are: Intel optimization manuals, Agner Fog, Paul Hsieh, Michael Abrash.

Comment: @noop: Wouldn't any efficiency gain in the loop iteration be lost by the added work required by `a[N+i]` instead of `a[i]`.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey both a[N+i] and a[i] generate one instruction on Intel architecture if N is constant. Also, if N is not constant, you just replace a[N + i] by a_end[i] where int *a_end = a + N. And since the value of a + N is not changed inside of the loop body, it is possible that optimizer will perform this substitution for you.

Answer (score 10):

Please don't let the question of "which one is faster" be the deciding factor of which to use.  Chances are you're never going to care that much, and besides, programmer reading time is far more expensive than machine time.

Use whichever makes most sense to the human reading the code.

Comment: I believe it is wrong to prefer vague readability improvements to actual efficiency gains and overall clarity of intent.

Comment: My term "programmer reading time" is roughly analogous to "clarity of intent".

"Actual efficiency gains" are often immeasurable, close enough to zero to call them zero.  In the OP's case, unless the code has been profiled to find that the ++i is a bottleneck, the question of which one is faster is a waste of time and programmer thought units.

Comment: Difference in readability between ++i and i++ is only a matter of personal preference, but ++i clearly implies simpler operation than i++, despite result being equivalent for trivial cases and simple data types when optimizing compiler is involved. Therefore ++i is a winner for me, when specific properties of post-increment are not necessary.

Comment: You are saying what I am saying.  It is more important to show intent and improve readability than to worry about "efficiency."

Comment: I still can't agree. If readability stands higher on your list of priorities then maybe your choice of programming language is wrong. C/C++ primary purpose is writing efficient code.

Answer (score 8):

@Mark
Even though the compiler is allowed to optimize away the (stack based) temporary copy of the variable and gcc (in recent versions) is doing so,
doesn't mean **all** compilers will always do so.

I just tested it with the compilers we use in our current project and 3 out of 4 do not optimize it.

Never assume the compiler gets it right, especially if the possibly faster, but never slower code is as easy to read.

If you don't have a really stupid implementation of one of the operators in your code:

**Alwas prefer ++i over i++.**

Comment: Just curious... why do you use 4 different C compilers in one project? Or in one team or one company, for that matter?

Comment: When creating games for consoles every platform brings it's own compiler/toolchain. In a perfect world we could use gcc/clang/llvm for all targets, but in this world we have to put up with Microsoft, Intel, Metroworks, Sony, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I have been reading through most of the answers here and many of the comments, and I didn't see any reference to the **one** instance that I could think of where `i++` is more efficient than `++i` (and perhaps surprisingly `--i` *was* more efficient than `i--`). That is for C compilers for the DEC PDP-11!

The PDP-11 had assembly instructions for pre-decrement of a register and post-increment, but not the other way around. The instructions allowed any "general-purpose" register to be used as a stack pointer. So if you used something like `*(i++)` it could be compiled into a single assembly instruction, while `*(++i)` could not.

This is obviously a very esoteric example, but it does provide the exception where post-increment is more efficient(or I should say *was*, since there isn't much demand for PDP-11 C code these days).

Comment: @daShier. +1, though I disagree, this is not that esoteric, or at least it shouldn't be. C was co-developed with Unix at AT&T Bell Labs in the early 70's when the PDP-11 was the target processor. In the Unix source code from this era post increment, "i++", is more prevalent partly because the developers knew when the value is assigned, "j = i++", or used as an index, "a[i++] = n", the code would be slightly faster (and smaller). It seems they got into the habit of using post increment unless pre was required. Others learned by reading their code and also picked up this habit.

Comment: The 68000 has the same feature, post-increment and pre-decrement are supported in hardware (as addressing modes), but not the other way around. The Motorola team was, um, inspired by the DEC PDP-11.

Comment: @jimhark, yes, I'm one of those PDP-11 programmers that transitioned to the 68000 and still use `--i` and `i++`.

Answer (score 5):

In C, the compiler can generally optimize them to be the same if the result is unused.

However, in C++ if using other types that provide their own ++ operators, the prefix version is likely to be faster than the postfix version.  So, if you don't need the postfix semantics, it is better to use the prefix operator.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of a situation where postfix is slower than prefix increment:

Imagine a processor with register `A` is used as accumulator and it's the only register used in many instructions (some small microcontrollers are actually like this).

Now imagine the following program and their translation into a hypothetical assembly:

Prefix increment:

```
a = ++b + c;

; increment b
LD    A, [&b]
INC   A
ST    A, [&b]

; add with c
ADD   A, [&c]

; store in a
ST    A, [&a]
```

Postfix increment:

```
a = b++ + c;

; load b
LD    A, [&b]

; add with c
ADD   A, [&c]

; store in a
ST    A, [&a]

; increment b
LD    A, [&b]
INC   A
ST    A, [&b]
```

Note how the value of `b` was forced to be reloaded. With prefix increment, the compiler can just increment the value and go ahead with using it, possibly avoid reloading it since the desired value is already in the register after the increment. However, with postfix increment, the compiler has to deal with two values, one the old and one the incremented value which as I show above results in one more memory access.

Of course, if the value of the increment is not used, such as a single `i++;` statement, the compiler can (and does) simply generate an increment instruction regardless of postfix or prefix usage.

---

As a side note, I'd like to mention that an expression in which there is a `b++` cannot simply be converted to one with `++b` without any additional effort (for example by adding a `- 1`). So comparing the two if they are part of some expression is not really valid. Often, where you use `b++` inside an expression you cannot use `++b`, so even if `++b` were potentially more efficient, it would simply be wrong. Exception is of course if the expression is begging for it (for example `a = b++ + 1;` which can be changed to `a = ++b;`).

Comment: On a superscalar CPU, your example could maybe run faster with postfix, because b+c can be done in parallel to b++.

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer pre-increment, however ...

I wanted to point out that even in the case of calling the operator++ function, the compiler will be able to optimize away the temporary if the function gets inlined.  Since the operator++ is usually short and often implemented in the header, it is likely to get inlined.

So, for practical purposes, there likely isn't much of a difference between the performance of the two forms.  However, I always prefer pre-increment since it seems better to directly express what I"m trying to say, rather than relying on the optimizer to figure it out.

Also, giving the optmizer less to do likely means the compiler runs faster.

Comment: Your posting is C++-specific while the question is about C. In any case, your answer is wrong: for custom post-increment operators the compiler will generally *not* be able to produce as efficient code.

Comment: He states "if the function gets inlined", and that makes his reasoning correct.

Comment: Since C does not provide operator overloading, the pre vs. post question is largely uninteresting.  The compiler can optimize away an unused temp using the same logic that is applied to any other unused, primitively computed value.  See the selected answer for a sample.

Answer (score -1):

My C is a little rusty, so I apologize in advance.  Speedwise, I can understand the results.  But, I am confused as to how both files came out to the same MD5 hash.  Maybe a for loop runs the same, but wouldn't the following 2 lines of code generate different assembly?

```
myArray[i++] = "hello";
```

vs

```
myArray[++i] = "hello";
```

The first one writes the value to the array, then increments i.  The second increments i then writes to the array.  I'm no assembly expert, but I just don't see how the same executable would be generated by these 2 different lines of code.

Just my two cents.

Comment: @Jason Z The compiler optimization happens before the assembly is finished being generated, it would see that the i variable is not used anywhere else on the same line, so holding its value would be a waste, it probably effectively flips it to i++. But that's just a guess. I can't wait till one of my lecturers tries to say it's faster and I get to be the guy who corrects a theory with practical evidence. I can almost feel the animosity already ^_^

Comment: "My C is a little rusty, so I apologize in advance." Nothing wrong with your C, but you didn't read the original question in full: "Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i _if the resulting value is not used?_" Note the italics. In your example, the 'result' of i++/++i **is** used, but in the idiomatic for loop, the 'result' of the pre/postincrement operator isn't used so the compiler can do what it likes.

Comment: in your example the code would be different, because you're using the value.  the example where they were the same was only using the ++ for the increment, and not using the value returned by either.

Comment: Fix: "the compiler would see that the return value of i++ is not used, so it would flip it to ++i". What you wrote is wrong also because you can't have i together with one of i++, i++ on the same line (statement), that result is undefined.

Comment: Changing `foo[i++]` to `foo[++i]` without changing anything else would obviously change program semantics, but on some processors when using a compiler without a loop-hoisting optimization logic, incrementing `p` and `q` once and then running a loop which performs e.g. `*(p++)=*(q++);` would be faster than using a loop which performs `*(++pp)=*(++q);`.  For very tight loops on some processors the speed difference may be significant (more than 10%), but that's probably the only case in C where post-increment is materially faster than pre-increment.