# Performance difference between post- and pre- increment operators?

Tags: java, performance

In Java, would there be any performance impact in using post increment vs pre increment operator? (In other languages, a pre-increment can be faster than a post-increment in certain contexts.)

For example, is there a performance difference in these loops?

```
for (int n = 0; idx < max; ++idx) { /* Note pre-increment */
  f(max);
}
```

Vs.

```
for (int n = 0; idx < max; idx++) { /* Note post-increment */
  f(max);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no difference, performance -wise

Comment: Run a test and find out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Very basic Code Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110764/very-basic-code-performance)

Comment: If you don't mind, what brings this question up?

Comment: This is true only on anciiiiient compilers (notice the number of i's? )

Comment: OpenJDK 16 compiler produces same bytecode for both

Answer (score 23):

A performance question only makes sense in a context where the functional behavior is identical (since, if the functionality is different, a correct behavior is superior to a minutely-faster one), so I'm assuming that you're referring to a situation where the value of the expression is not used? That is, where the only purpose of the expression is to increment `i`? In such a situation, the answer is no: no performance difference, and in fact, no difference whatsoever. I just compiled this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(final String args[])
    {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

and computed the MD5 checksum of the resulting `Foo.class`; and, similarly for a version with `++i` instead. They had the same checksum, indicating that the two versions were compiled into the *exact* same bytecode, and would therefore perform *literally* identically.

(Naturally, this could, in theory, depend on the compiler. A different compiler might decide to compile `i++` differently from `++i` even in a context where they're equivalent. But I doubt that, and it's *really* not worth worrying about even if it the case.)

Answer (score 3):

The required runtime for the increment itself ought to be the same, but if you are using a pre- or post-increment obviously may have impact on the performance of the surrounding code and a post-increment can in more situations be optimized away.

There are also some non-obvious cases, where the performance of the surrounding code is changed. At least when run with Oracle's server VM on x86 or x64 hardware, the following loops have a significant difference in their runtime:

```
long a=0, b=0;
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
    b = 3;
    a += i * (b++);
}
```

...

```
long a=0, b=0;
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
    b = 3;
    a += i * (++b);
}
```

Comment: Which one was faster?

Comment: @xilpex Do you honestly believe that I can answer that question more than 8 years after I wrote this answer?

Comment: Ah, my apologies-- I hadn't seen that :)

Comment: the faster one is the one with ++b