# Is there any difference between i++ and ++i in javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript

I know, in c++, ++i is better then i++.

```
++i;  // Fetch i, increment it, and return it  
i++;  // Fetch i, copy it, increment i, return copy
```

Here's [same question about c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261708/i-or-i-in-for-loops).

So, what about javascript ?

Comment: Same semantics as C++. (Also it's a little weird to say that pre-increment is "better" than post-increment. It's *different*, but I don't see why it'd be better.)

Comment: Define "better". Performance? If so, forget it. I don't believe you'll  be able to enjoy the benefit (if any) of that level of optimization in JS.

Comment: [Tested](http://jsperf.com/prefix-or-postfix-increment) the performance on my iPhone and they are almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from **Guffa**:

The difference between i++ and ++i is the value of the expression.

'The value `i++` is the value of `i` before the increment. The value of `++i` is the value of `i` after the increment.

Example:

```
var i = 42;
alert(i++); // shows 42
alert(i); // shows 43
i = 42;
alert(++i); // shows 43
alert(i); // shows 43
```

The `i--` and `--i` operators works the same way.'

So *basically,* the only difference is the result of the increment.

Comment: No, they do not do the same thing. They return different values.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using the result of the increment, either in an assignment or as part of an expression, there's absolutely no difference between pre- and post-increment.

If you're using the result, pre-increment may be slightly faster because it doesn't need to save the old value while it's incrementing. But if you're using the result, you need to choose which form to use based on which value you need to assign -- you can't usually make the decision based on performance.