# ActionScript 3 - What do these codes do?

Tags: actionscript-3, code-translation

I'me trying to understand some Action Script 3 features in order to port some code.

### Code 1

How does the "++" influences the index part mean? If `idx_val=0` then what xvaluer index will be modified?

```
xvaluer(++idx_val) = "zero";
```

### Code 2

Then I have this: what is the meaning of this part of code?
What is being assigned to bUnicode in the last 3 lines?
(can you explain me the "<<"s and ">>"s)

```
bUnicode = new Array(2);
i = (i + 1);
i = (i + 1);
bUnicode[0] = aData[(i + 1)] << 2 | aData[(i + 1)] >> 4;
i = (i + 1);
bUnicode[1] = aData[i] << 4 | aData[(i + 1)] >> 2;
```

### Code 3

I haven't the faintest idea of what is happening here.
What is "as" ? What is the "?" ?

```
bL = c > BASELENGTH ? (INVALID) : (s_bReverseLPad[c]);
```

### Code 4

What is "&&" ?

```
  if ((i + 1) < aData.length && s_bReverseUPad(aData((i + 1))) != INVALID)
```

### Code 5

What is "as" ? What is the "?" ?

```
n2 = c < 0 ? (c + 256)  as  (c)
bOut.push(n1 >> 2 & 63)
bOut.push((n1 << 4 | n2 >> 4) & 63)//What is the single "&" ?
bOut.push(n2 << 2 & 63)
```

Finally, what are the differences between "||" and "|", and between "=" and "==" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Code 1:** `++i` is almost the same thing as `i++` or `i += 1;` The only real difference is that it's modified before it is evaluated. [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261708/i-or-i-in-for-loops)

**Code 2:** `<<` and `>>` are bitwise shifts, they literally shift bits by one place. You really need to understand `Binary` before you can mess about with these operators. I would recommend reading [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301) all the way through.

**Code 3:** This one is called `Ternary Operator` and it's actually quite simple. It's a one line `if / else` statement. `bL = c > BASELENGTH ? (INVALID) : (s_bReverseLPad[c]);` is equivalent to:

```
if(c > BASELENGTH) {
    bL = INVALID;
} else {
    bL = s_bReverseLPad[c];
}
```

[Read more about it here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

**Code 4:** *"The conditional-AND operator (`&&`) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary."* There is also the conditional-OR operator to keep in mind (`||`).
As an example of the AND operator here is some code:

```
if(car.fuel && car.wheels) car.move();
```

[Read more about it here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#logical_AND)

**Code 5:** [From AS3 Reference:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#as) `as` *"Evaluates whether an expression specified by the first operand is a member of the data type specified by the second operand."* So basically you're casting one type to another, but only if it's possible otherwise you will get `null`.

`&` is `Bitwise AND operator` and `|` is `Bitwise OR operator`,  again refer to [this article.](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301)

`=` and `==` are two different operators. The former(`=`) is called `Basic Assignment` meaning it is used when you do any kind of assignment like: `i = 3;`. The later(`==`) is called `Equal to` and it is used to check if a value is equal to something else. `if(i == 3) // DO STUFF;`. Pretty straight forward.

The only part that doesn't make sense to me is the single question mark. `Ternary Operator` needs to have both `?` and `:`. Does this code actually run for you? Perhaps a bit more context would help. What type is `c`?

`n2 = c < 0 ? (c + 256)  as  (c)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm done. I you wanted some more context, here it is: http://pastebin.com/piFaSULT

Comment: Looks like you made a copy error. The line is actually `n2 = c < 0 ? (c + 256) : (c);` And that means it's a `ternary operator`!