# Efficient way to calculate Hawk's process gradient

Tags: r, rcpp

I am interested in calculating the following quantity

`B(i) = \sum_{j < i}(x_i-x_j)exp^{-\beta(x_i - x_j)}`

which is part of computing the gradient wrt one of the parameters of a Hawk's process likelihood (more information can be found here: http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/031_1_0145.pdf).

Beta is just a constant for the shake of the problem and x_i is my i-th data point.

I am trying to calculate the above quantity in RCPP, using the following chunk of code:

```
for( int i = 1; i< x.size();i++) {
    double temp=0;
    for(int j=0; j<=i-1;j++){
      temp+=(x[i]-x[j])*exp(-beta*(x[i]-x[j]));

    }
```

but it is highly inefficient and slow. Any suggestion on how this formula could be speeded-up?

Comment: How large is `x`? Have you considered parallel execution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard operations are very fast in C++ (`+`, `-`, etc).
Yet, `exp` is more complicated to compute, so slower.

So, if we want some performance improvement, the more likely would be to be able to precompute the `exp` computations.

Here, `B(i) = \sum_{j < i}(x_i-x_j)exp^{-\beta(x_i - x_j)}` is equivalent to `B(i) = \sum_{j < i}(x_i-x_j) / exp^{\beta x_i} * exp^{\beta x_j}` so that you can precompute the `exp` for each index only (and also put the one depending on `i` out of the loop). By refactoring it, you can do other precomputations. So, I put here the two previous solutions then my incremental solutions:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_org(Rcpp::NumericVector x, double beta = 3) {

  int n = x.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector B = Rcpp::no_init( n - 1);

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    double temp = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++) {
      temp += (x[i] - x[j]) * exp(-beta * (x[i] - x[j]));
    }

    B(i - 1) = temp;
  }

  return B;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_cache(Rcpp::NumericVector x, double beta = 3) {

  int n = x.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector B = Rcpp::no_init( n - 1);

  double x_i;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {

    double temp = 0;
    x_i = x[i];

    for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; ++j) {
      temp += (x_i - x[j]) * 1 / exp(beta * (x_i - x[j]));
    }

    B(i - 1) = temp;
  }

  return B;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_cache_2(Rcpp::NumericVector x, 
                                         double beta = 3) {

  int i, j, n = x.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector B(n);
  Rcpp::NumericVector x_exp = exp(beta * x);

  double temp;
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    temp = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      temp += (x[i] - x[j]) * x_exp[j] / x_exp[i];
    }

    B[i] = temp;
  }

  return B;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_cache_3(Rcpp::NumericVector x, 
                                         double beta = 3) {

  int i, j, n = x.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector B(n);
  Rcpp::NumericVector x_exp = exp(beta * x);

  double temp;
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    temp = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      temp += (x[i] - x[j]) * x_exp[j];
    }

    B[i] = temp / x_exp[i];
  }

  return B;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_cache_4(Rcpp::NumericVector x, 
                                         double beta = 3) {

  Rcpp::NumericVector exp_pre = exp(beta * x);
  Rcpp::NumericVector exp_pre_cumsum = cumsum(exp_pre);
  Rcpp::NumericVector x_exp_pre_cumsum = cumsum(x * exp_pre);
  return (x * exp_pre_cumsum - x_exp_pre_cumsum) / exp_pre;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_cache_5(Rcpp::NumericVector x, 
                                         double beta = 3) {

  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector B(n);
  double exp_pre, exp_pre_cumsum = 0, x_exp_pre_cumsum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    exp_pre = exp(beta * x[i]);
    exp_pre_cumsum += exp_pre;
    x_exp_pre_cumsum += x[i] * exp_pre;
    B[i] = (x[i] * exp_pre_cumsum - x_exp_pre_cumsum) / exp_pre;
  }

  return B;
}



/*** R
set.seed(111)

x = rnorm(1e3)

all.equal(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache(x)
)
all.equal(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache_2(x)[-1]
)
all.equal(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache_3(x)[-1]
)

all.equal(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache_4(x)[-1]
)

all.equal(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache_5(x)[-1]
)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache(x),
  hawk_process_cache_2(x),
  hawk_process_cache_3(x),
  hawk_process_cache_4(x),
  hawk_process_cache_5(x)
) 
*/
```

Benchmark for `x  = rnorm(1e3)`:

```
Unit: microseconds
                    expr       min         lq        mean     median         uq       max neval   cld
     hawk_process_org(x) 19801.686 20610.0365 21017.89339 20816.1385 21157.4900 25548.042   100    d 
   hawk_process_cache(x) 20506.903 21062.1370 21534.47944 21297.8710 21775.2995 26030.106   100     e
 hawk_process_cache_2(x)  1895.809  2038.0105  2087.20696  2065.8220  2103.0695  3212.874   100   c  
 hawk_process_cache_3(x)   430.084   458.3915   494.09627   474.2840   503.0885  1580.282   100  b   
 hawk_process_cache_4(x)    50.657    55.2930    71.60536    57.6105    63.5700  1190.260   100 a    
 hawk_process_cache_5(x)    43.373    47.0155    60.43775    49.6640    55.6235   842.288   100 a
```

**This is much more effective than trying to gain nanoseconds from small optimizations that are likely to get your code more difficult to read.**

---

But still, let's try the optimizations proposed by @coatless on my very last solution:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_cache_6(Rcpp::NumericVector x, 
                                         double beta = 3) {

  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector B = Rcpp::no_init(n);
  double x_i, exp_pre, exp_pre_cumsum = 0, x_exp_pre_cumsum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x_i = x[i];
    exp_pre = exp(beta * x_i);
    exp_pre_cumsum += exp_pre;
    x_exp_pre_cumsum += x_i * exp_pre;
    B[i] = (x_i * exp_pre_cumsum - x_exp_pre_cumsum) / exp_pre;
  }

  return B;
}
```

Benchmark for `x  = rnorm(1e6)`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 hawk_process_cache_5(x) 42.52886 43.53653 45.28427 44.46688 46.74129  57.38046   100   a
 hawk_process_cache_6(x) 42.14778 43.19054 45.93252 44.28445 46.51052 153.30447   100   a
```

Still not very convincing..

Comment: These answers are not equivalent. You negated subsetting inside the C++ function and left that in R. So, the benchmarks displayed are bogus. Though, I am sure there are gains over the original method.

Comment: Also, I think you could _increase_ the speed by using `no_init(size)` to initialize the `NumericVectors` without the default fill of 0's.

Comment: @coatless For the first comment, you are talking about the `[-1]`? For the second comment, I edited `hawk_process_cache_6` to use `no_init`.

Comment: Yes, you are not subsetting within the _C++_ function. e.g. `hawk_process_org(x),
  != hawk_process_cache_5(x)`. You're benchmark is biased as a result. I think the speed up in terms of `cumsum` will still greatly improve the results as you reduce the exp() call from N^2 to N since there is a built in cache as a result. I would also suggest `no_init()` for your own variants.  I'm sure that would speed up the process more.

Comment: I computed a vector of `n` elements because I think this is what the OP needs. Actually, it is more computation than just `n - 1`. Also, using `no_init` in the last solution didn't really change the benchmark. I think those are not the optimizations that a developer should focus on.

Comment: It's off-by-one with `n` as one place disappear since this is a differencing op with `x[i] - x[j]`. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html

Comment: @F.Privé, it's is true that `no_init` has little effect here, but consider a matrix with a hundred million rows and 100s of columns.... I have seen having `no_init_matrix` decrease running time by 40% in such cases. Still though, nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. In my tests combining the two answers does give a further performance boost (benchmarks further down):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector hawk_process_cache_combined(NumericVector x, 
                                         double beta = 3) {

  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector B = Rcpp::no_init(n-1);
  double exp_pre(exp(beta * x[0]));
  double exp_pre_cumsum(exp_pre);
  double x_exp_pre_cumsum(x[0] * exp_pre);
  double x_i;

  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    x_i = x[i];
    exp_pre = exp(beta * x_i);
    exp_pre_cumsum += exp_pre;
    x_exp_pre_cumsum += x_i * exp_pre;
    B[i-1] = (x_i * exp_pre_cumsum - x_exp_pre_cumsum) / exp_pre;
  }

  return B;
}

all.equal(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache_combined(x)
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Now while the original formulation is "embarrassingly parallel", this is no longer the case for this expression. However, prefix scan algorithms like `cumsum` can also be parallelized. And libraries like [ArrayFire](https://arrayfire.com/) provide interfaces to such algorithms using the GPU. Using [RcppArrayFire](https://www.daqana.org/rcpparrayfire/) one can write based on F. Privé's `hawk_process_cached_4`:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArrayFire)]]
#include <RcppArrayFire.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
af::array hawk_process_af(RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32> x, 
                          double beta = 3) {

  af::array exp_pre = exp(beta * x);
  af::array exp_pre_cumsum = af::accum(exp_pre);
  af::array x_exp_pre_cumsum = af::accum(x * exp_pre);
  af::array result = (x * exp_pre_cumsum - x_exp_pre_cumsum) / exp_pre;
  return result(af::seq(1, af::end));
}
```

Here the results are not exactly equal, since my driver/card only supports single precision floats:

```
all.equal(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_af(x)
)
#> [1] "Mean relative difference: 3.437819e-07"
```

With double precision one would write `f64` above and obtain identical results. Now for  the benchmarks:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(1e3)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  hawk_process_af(x),
  hawk_process_cache_combined(x),
  hawk_process_cache_5(x)[-1]
) 
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                            expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq      max neval
#>              hawk_process_af(x) 245.281 277.4625 338.92232 298.5410 346.576 1030.045   100
#>  hawk_process_cache_combined(x)  35.343  39.0120  43.69496  40.7770  45.264    84.242   100
#>     hawk_process_cache_5(x)[-1]  52.408  57.8580  65.55799  60.5265  67.965  125.864   100
x <- rnorm(1e6)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  hawk_process_af(x),
  hawk_process_cache_combined(x),
  hawk_process_cache_5(x)[-1]
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>              hawk_process_af(x) 27.54936 28.42794 30.93452 29.20025 32.40667  49.41888   100
#>  hawk_process_cache_combined(x) 34.00380 36.84497 40.74862 39.03649 41.85902 111.51628   100
#>     hawk_process_cache_5(x)[-1] 47.02501 53.24702 57.94747 55.35018 58.42097 130.89737   100
```

So for small vectors, the combined approach is faster, while for longer once offloading to the GPU pays off. All this not with some high power GPU but simple on-board graphics:

```
RcppArrayFire::arrayfire_info()
#> ArrayFire v3.5.1 (OpenCL, 64-bit Linux, build 0a675e8)
#> [0] BEIGNET: Intel(R) HD Graphics Skylake ULT GT2, 4096 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an O(N^2) operation without factoring in the cost of exp. Any tweaks are likely to yield minimal improvements.

A few quick suggestions:

- *cache* the value of `x[i]` on the outer loop as you are repeatedly subsetting that in the inner loop.
- switch from using `exp(-beta * ..)` to `1/exp(beta*(x ... ))`
- use `++i` instead of `i++` to avoid [a slight performance hiccup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261743/1345455) since you avoid a copy of `i` that the latter does.

---

Original code:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_org(Rcpp::NumericVector x, double beta = 3) {

  int n = x.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector B = Rcpp::no_init( n - 1);

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    double temp = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++) {
      temp += (x[i] - x[j]) * exp(-beta * (x[i] - x[j]));
    }

    B(i - 1) = temp;
  }

  return B;
}
```

Modified code:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector hawk_process_cache(Rcpp::NumericVector x, double beta = 3) {

  int n = x.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector B = Rcpp::no_init( n - 1);

  double x_i;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {

    double temp = 0;
    x_i = x[i];

    for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; ++j) {
      temp += (x_i - x[j]) * 1 / exp(beta * (x_i - x[j]));
    }

    B(i - 1) = temp;
  }

  return B;
}
```

Test

```
set.seed(111)

x = rnorm(1e4)

all.equal(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache(x)
)
#> [1] TRUE

bench_func = microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  hawk_process_org(x),
  hawk_process_cache(x)
)

bench_func
#> Unit:milliseconds
#>                 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max   neval
#> hawk_process_org(x)   436.5349 465.9674 505.9606 481.4703 500.6652 894.7477   100
#> hawk_process_cache(x) 446.0499 454.9098 485.3830 468.6580 494.9457 799.0940   100
```

So, you get marginally better results under the recommendations.