# Int Argument in operator++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, arguments

```
class myClass
{
    public:

    void operator++()
    {
        // ++myInstance.
    }

    void operator++(int)
    {
        // myInstance++.
    }
}
```

Besides letting the compiler distinguish between `myInstance++` and `++myInstance`, is the optional `int` argument in `operator++` actually for anything?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @Konrad said, the int argument is not used for anything, other than to distingush between the pre-increment and post-increment forms.

Note however that your operators should return a value.  Pre-increment should return a reference, and post-increment should return by-value.  To wit:

```
class myClass
{

public:

myClass& operator++()
{
    // ++myInstance. 
    return * this;   
}
myClass operator++(int)
{
    // myInstance++.
    myClass orig = *this;
    ++(*this);  // do the actual increment
    return orig;
}
};
```

### EDIT:

As  Gene Bushuyev mentions correctly below, it is not an absolute requirement that `operator++` return non-void.  However, in most cases (I can't think of an exception) you'll need to.  Especially if you want to assign the results of the operator to some other value, such as:

```
myClass a;
myClass x = a++;
```

### EDIT2:

Also, with the postimcrement version, you will return the object before it was incremented.  This is typically done using a local temporary.  See above.

Comment: returning something is probably what one wants, though it's not an absolute requirement. Also, you probably return a temporary with original value from `operator++(int)`, not `*this`. This is also not an absolute requirement.

Comment: @Gene:  True, not an absolute requirement.  Edited.

Answer (score 12):

> is the optional int argument in operator++ actually for anything?

No. The only purpose is to distinguish between the two overloads. Quite disappointing, I know. ;-)