# using ++counter instead of counter++ in for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c)

I saw many places where they use for loops like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){ do_stuff(); }
```

instead of (which I -& most of people- use)

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){ do_stuff(); }
```

`++i` should exactly give the same result as `i++` (unless operators overloaded differential). I saw it for normal for-loops and STL iterated for loops.

Why do they use `++i` instead of `i++`? does any coding rules recommends this?

**EDIT**: closed cause I found that it is exact duplicate of [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c)

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.15

Comment: I found that is it exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Comment: While in this case not neccessary and funtionally indentical, it is just good practice, because as soon as `i` is of class type (e.g. an iterator), `++i` is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

simply put: `++x is pre-increment and x++ is post-increment that is in the first x is incremented before being used and in the second x is incremented after being used.`

example code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;

    printf("x=%d\n", ++x);
    printf("x=%d\n", x++);
    printf("x=%d\n", x);

}
```

o/p:

```
x=6
x=6
x=7
```

Comment: They differ only in their result, which in this case is discarded.  And it's `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Answer (score 2):

The two are indeed identical, as the third part is executed after each iteration of the loop and it's return value is not used for anything. It's just a matter of preference.

Comment: They're *not* identical, especially if `i` is not an integer type.

Comment: @awoodland: The operators themselves aren't, but if used as the counting expression of a for loop like described in the question they are functionally identical.

Comment: In the OPs case, they are functionally identical.

Comment: `i++` and `++i` are not identical but in this case as a third statement of a for-loop the behaviour of that loop is exactly the same if the ++Operator is not modifyed. The answer of Kaivosukeltaja is in this case correct: it is a matter of preference