# std::list iterator

Tags: c++, list, std

The following code instead of returning a pointer back to an audioResource it returns
something else which is invalid, i've gone through with a debugger and the problem is with this line

```
return *list_it;
```

Here is my function:

```
AudioResource* AudioManager::getResource(const unsigned int ID)
{
    std::list<AudioResource*>::iterator list_it;
    for(list_it = m_resources.begin(); list_it!= m_resources.end(); list_it++)
    {
        if((*list_it)->getID()==ID)
            {
std::cout<<*(*list_it)->getFileName();
            return *list_it;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

O and I have tried putting it as (*list_it) but i got the same results =s

How it is populated...

```
Resource* AudioManager::addResource(const unsigned int ID, 
      const std::string fileName,  const unsigned int scope,
      const std::string type)
{
     AudioResource* temp;
     if(type == "AUDIO_TYPE_SAMPLE")
     {
          temp = new AudioResource(ID,fileName,scope,
                      RESOURCE_AUDIO,AUDIO_TYPE_SAMPLE);
          m_resources.push_back(temp);
     }
     else if(type == "AUDIO_TYPE_STREAM")
     {
          temp = new AudioResource(ID,fileName,scope,
                    RESOURCE_AUDIO,AUDIO_TYPE_STREAM);
          m_resources.push_back(temp);
     }

     return temp;
}
```

call to get resource

```
cout<<AudioManager::getInstance()->getResource(IDnum)->getFileName();
```

Comment: Design thoughts: Why a `list` not a `vector`? Or a `map`? Why raw pointers? :)

Comment: are you sure that `AudioResource*` is valid? Maybe the iterator is correct, is the backing list that's wrong.

Comment: Looks okay as is (nit: post-increment might give worse performance). How do you initialize m_resources?

Comment: Can you show how `m_resources` is populated?

Comment: Everything looks ok. I'd say some other code deleted a pointer from the collection and didn't remove it or set it to `nullptr`.

Comment: Aside from the fact that list is almost certainly the wrong collection, your could should either return an AudioResource* that has getID()==ID or a nullptr. What makes you think what it returns is invalid?

Comment: @troclosan pre-increment is a minor performance enhancement (which the compiler may optimise away anyway) compared to all the others here.

Comment: @dario_ramos if that happened you'd get an error in the loop when you try calling ->GetID() on it. Of course it would be undefined behaviour so you could get anything happen including what he OP is seeing, but I doubt that's the bug.

Comment: Can `m_resources` be manipulated from multiple threads?

Comment: provided how the list is populated now =)

Comment: @phresnel post-increment leads to creation of a temporary object. and i realize that using of pre-increment not fix subj problem

Comment: The list is populated because when I went throught with the debugger all the information within the object was still there such as file name so the problem is how I return the object

Comment: @triclosan Actual performance measurements that I did showed no difference between pre- and post-incrementation, despite everyone's claims to the opposite.  Compilers aren't that stupid.  (Moving the call to `end()` out of the loop did make a difference.  But not enough to be worth the effort generally.)

Comment: Tackling the problem from another side: How does the call to `getResource` look like? And how do you know that what you return is invalid? This is getting to the point of psychic debugging without further context. Maybe you can reduce the problem to a small http://sscce.org?

Comment: Added, its just a cin call to get the IDnum, it is invalid because the filename is not the proper filename its a bunch of numbers for one. Secondly if i run the code in debug I can see the value of the filename correctly found. I have found a possible hint to the solution and will edit my code to show you

Comment: std::cout<<*(*list_it)->getFileName();
This line does return the proper information but no how to use that to return in AudioResource* format =s

Comment: @JamesKanze: I published [my benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9519095/76722), will you publish yours, too?

Comment: @phresnel How much of this can be cleaned up?  The comment section is getting a little long.  Please update the question and/or relevant answers with the information in the comments and then remove them.

Comment: @ChrisCondy How much of this can be cleaned up?  The comment section is getting a little long.  Please update the question and/or relevant answers with the information in the comments and then remove them.

Comment: @JamesKanze How much of this can be cleaned up?  The comment section is getting a little long.  Please update the question and/or relevant answers with the information in the comments and then remove them.

Comment: @Xeo How much of this can be cleaned up?  The comment section is getting a little long.  Please update the question and/or relevant answers with the information in the comments and then remove them.

Answer (score 2):

If `type` is neither of the two values an uninitialized pointer is added to `m_resources`:

```
AudioResource* temp;
if(type == "AUDIO_TYPE_SAMPLE")
{
    temp = new AudioResource(ID,fileName,scope,RESOURCE_AUDIO,AUDIO_TYPE_SAMPLE);
}
else if(type == "AUDIO_TYPE_STREAM")
{
    temp = new AudioResource(ID,fileName,scope,RESOURCE_AUDIO,AUDIO_TYPE_STREAM);
}
m_resources.push_back(temp);
```

Initialize `temp` to `NULL` and only add to `m_resources` if `temp != NULL`.

Also, the function returns the same uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Code has been amended so that nothing is pushed onto the list if is not in the else statement and problem still is there, thanks for trying tho =)

Comment: The uninitialized pointer is still being returned: it is used by the caller?

Comment: No for now the return data is ignored, as I have not finished coding the rest of the resource manager =)

Comment: But that isn't his code. He is doing push_back within the ifs. True the function will return an invalid pointer but it doesn't get added to the list as far as I see.

Comment: @ChrisCondy, do elements get removed from `m_resources` anywhere?

Comment: @hmjd: See my answer, he already answered that that isn't the case.

Comment: @Xeo, ok. Nothing removes from `m_resources`. Wonder if anything `delete`s an element of `m_resources` without removing it from `m_resources`?

Comment: @ChrisCondy, does anything `delete` an element from `m_resources`? I do not mean remove an element from `m_resources`.

Comment: Nothing is ever removed from m_resources, I havnt even implemented it. And none of the elements are deleted as I have not written code to do that either =s

Answer (score 1):

You return `nullptr` in case the `ID` doesn't exist, but you never check against it at the call site, which will give you a null pointer access if the ID doesn't exist and which will likely create problems.

```
AudioManager::getInstance()->getResource(IDnum)->getFileName();
```

Change that to

```
AudioResource* res = AudioManager::getInstance()->getResource(IDnum);
if(res)
  std::cout << res->getFileName();
```

Comment: Code has been amended so this problem is avoided and still the orignal problem is there

Comment: where does he push it into the list?

Comment: @ChrisCondy: Do you have any code that removes things from the list? Do you have concurrent accesses to the list?

Comment: @CashCow: If you would've read the other comments, you would have noticed that the OP *changed* the code *after* our answers pointed the flaws out.

Comment: Nothing removes from the list and no i am not multithreading =)

Comment: @ChrisCondy: Okay, last idea... do you maybe access the list after the `AudioManager` is actually destroyed from somewhere else? A dangling pointer maybe?

Comment: Well the AudioManager is an singleton, so know the audiomanager isnt destroyed and the std::list<AudioResource*> m_resources; so its put on the stack? So maybe I should put this on the heap instead?

Comment: Well i tested by making std::list<AudioResource*> m_resources; a pointer to a list and putting it on the heap and still the same problem

Comment: @Chris: Okay, question: How exactly do you know that the return is invalid? What makes you think that?

Comment: Ok for one if i put in the code std::cout<<*(*list_it)->getFileName(); This line does return the proper information. Inside the getresource code =) once it has decided it has found the proper value.

Comment: @Xeo he made several revisions, only revision 3 has the faulty code and that wasn't on here for long. If he then changes it to fix the bug inline it becomes no longer a valid question so he should say it has been fixed.