# How do I Iterate over a vector of C++ strings?

Tags: c++, vector, loops

How do I iterate over this C++ vector?

`vector<string> features = {"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"};`

Comment: Yeah, that one's pretty trivial to find.

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
for(vector<string>::const_iterator i = features.begin(); i != features.end(); ++i) {
    // process i
    cout << *i << " "; // this will print all the contents of *features*
}
```

If you are using C++11, then this is legal too:

```
for(auto i : features) {
    // process i
    cout << i << " "; // this will print all the contents of *features*
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you means `++i` and not `i++`.

Comment: Actually it's the same thing.

Comment: [No, it is not!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) and you should be using a `const_iterator` not just a `iterator`.This is boiler plate code, You should learn it well and well enough to get it right even if asked when asleep.

Comment: Also, the `i` variable in the range-based for loop should be a const reference. Otherwise you are creating unnecessary copies of the vector's strings.

Comment: @Als - That's old info. Current compilers have no problems inlining either operator++ for std::vector, and optimize away any unused copies.

Comment: @BoPersson: You never know which compiler one might get to put up with,Besides it never hurts to write more correct and better code, especially in case of boiler plate codes.

Comment: I believe that in this context, it doesn't really matter if it is ++i or i++ and therefore there is no "correct" or "incorrect" way or even "better" way of coding. Given this context, there is no difference between post and pre incrementation.

Comment: @FanaticD I agree :)

Answer (score 14):

C++11, which you are using if this compiles, allows the following:

```
for (string& feature : features) {
    // do something with `feature`
}
```

[This is the range-based `for` loop.](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html)

If you don’t want to mutate the feature, you can also declare it as `string const&` (or just `string`, but that will cause an unnecessary copy).