# Iterating over a string vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently trying to split a string and store it into a `vector`.

For example,

```
std::string argData = "1:/path/to/file, 3:/path/to/differentfile, 4:/path/to/anotherfile";
vector<string> v = Util::split(argData, ",");
```

will return ["1:/path/to/file", "3:/path/to/differentfile", "4:/path/to/anotherfile"] in `v`.

What I would like to do is:

```
for each string in vector 
position = string.find(':')
```

How would I do this in C++? I do not have access to C++11 for auto.

Comment: Explore `std::stringstream` facilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-stdvector-unsigned-vs-signed-index-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Iterate over a vector of C++ strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170349/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-vector-of-c-strings)

Comment: Vectors without c++11? You could try using [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/). About the "find"-part, there is a function [`std::string::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: @Detonar Vectors are in c++98