# C++ Memory Error when using if(condition) return: Unbelievable

Tags: c++, if-statement, error-handling, return

Today I wrote some interesting code that convert an integer to Roman numerals. 
Whole running codes are here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string arabic2roman(int i){
//if(i==0) return "ZERO";

map<int, string> m;
m.insert(pair<int,string>(0,"ZERO"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(1,"I"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(4,"IV"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(5,"V"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(9,"IX"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(10,"X"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(40,"XL"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(50,"L"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(90,"XC"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(100,"C"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(400,"CD"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(500,"D"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(900,"CM"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(1000,"M"));

string roman;
map<int,string>::iterator iter;
for(iter=m.end();iter !=m.begin();iter--){
    while(i >=iter->first){
        roman+=iter->second;
        i-=iter->first;
    }
}
return roman;
}

int main(){
    int test=12345;
    cout << arabic2roman(test) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine on my Xcode 4.6.2 right now. But if remove "//" in line 8 right before 
if(i==0) return "ZERO", on Xcode 4.6.2, the program runs endlessly.
Can anybody explain this? Thanks!

Comment: " It crashed, and the program runs endlessly." which one is it?

Comment: I've coded C++ for going on 15 years, and **I'm** the bug-maker, not the language.

Comment: Because you are de-referencing the `end()` iterator? 3 years of C++ and you don't know you shouldn't do that? :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza stalker? :P

Comment: @John Would vote twice if I could. Add at least +5 years for me ...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the return "ZERO". It should create a temporary, which copied to the return value. The temporary return value, has the lifetime of the expression (just until the ending semicolon, after endl) and should not give any problem. You have a bad compiler. However, this code makes little sense. It does not pay to build a map just to make a single lookup, in general, it does not pay to build an index just for a single lookup, the index construction cost has to be amortized over many lookups.

Comment: I mean the whole program. It should output MMMMMMMMMMMMCCCXLV before removing "//", but after removing, the program is unstopped. I run this code on Xcode 4.6.2

Comment: Hey, hey why do you downvote this question?? Because the OP tries to blame the language, C++ is frustrating sometimes ...

Comment: I'm not sure why all of the downvotes on this question?  Oh well ....

Comment: `i` isn't zero, so it doesn't return `"ZERO"` and always goes on to try to execute the loop with the undefined iterator.

Comment: as the program has undefined behavior, anything can happen. With or without the redundant if

Comment: @John, Could not agree more. Good to see many coding magnets here!

Comment: @juanchopanza, sorry I did not get that! Why comment that if-return line, this program works??

Comment: De-referencing the `end()` iterator is undefined behaviour. In practice this can mean that your program can end up doing all kinds of non-intuitive things, and it is very hard (even pointless) to reason it out. Your best bet is to fix that problem first, then see if it works.

Comment: @BalogPal, please, how will you revise this program to make it robust?

Comment: Just to note, Roman numerals probably weren't used to represent numbers larger than 3999.

Comment: as others already said, make it `for(iter=m.end(),--iter;iter !=m.begin();--iter){` that stops dereferencing end iterator, uncommenting the 0-check, or make it check range

Comment: @BalogPal: My goddess, it works!!

Comment: you deserve it after editing out the original preamble of the question ;-)

Comment: @PeterWood: There are Roman numerals used for "larger" numbers, but it's not commonly used. Here's a reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RomanNumerals.html

Comment: @BalogPal _'you deserve it after editing out the original preamble of the question'_ That's at least my credit ;-) ...

Answer (score 8):

To iterate in reverse order, use rbegin and rend:

```
for(iter=m.rbegin();iter !=m.rend(); ++iter){
    while(i >=iter->first){
        roman+=iter->second;
        i-=iter->first;
    }
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/rbegin

Comment: +1 good spot and reduce to the real problem

Comment: oh, its true. I only copy-modify-paste the original code. I know the it++ behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Answer (score 7):

```
for(iter=m.end();iter !=m.begin();iter--){
    while(i >=iter->first){
        roman+=iter->second;
        i-=iter->first;
    }
}
```

On the first iteration, you dereference `m.end()` which is illegal. You were **unlucky** (no, not lucky) it appeared to work with that line commented out, because it was hiding this major bug.

Do it like everyone else, and start from `begin()`, using `iter++`.

Comment: or `rbegin()` to `rend()`.

Comment: Jesus! m.end() is a "THEORETICAL" iterator that follows the actual element! No wonder everybody says dereferencing!

Comment: Iterating forwards means the algorithm won't work. You have to subtract the largest values first.