# Best way to increase counter in Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++, performance, calculator, increment

Which is the best method for increasing a counter (integer) in java. I am interested in the cost of the operation.

```
int j = 0;
j = j + 1;
```

or

```
int i = 0;
i++;
```

It gives almost the same for small programs, but it differs for big calculations, the thousands of iterations.

Comment: With nearly any compiler, these are going to be identical.

Comment: for C++ ++i is  faster than i++, not sure about Java...

Comment: You left out `++j`, which, although usually optimized by the compiler, is preferred if you *don't* need the prior value, as it eliminates the *potential* for a non-elided temp to be used.

Comment: In Java, the performance is the same.

Comment: @Maxim Not sure that's the case with most compilers. I've heard urban legends to that effect, but not seen any assembly for it.

Comment: @Maxim That is extremely unlikely in C++ for an `int`, given a reasonable compiler. The generated assembly code should be the same.

Comment: @Maxim:with primitive types, the prefix and postfix arithmetic operations  have identical performance. With objects, however, postfix operators can cause the object to create a copy of itself to preserve its initial state (to be returned as a result of the operation), as well as causing the side-effect of the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk about increment or decrement , the first thing which come in mind is the operator used for increment or decrement i.e ++, --

In your first case of course that will do the increment job for you , but its indirect approach to increment techniques, and compiler will need to do two jobs, 1) Addition 2) Assignment.

In Second one the compiler Knows that it is increment operator , so it will increment that variable.

Answer (score 3):

In deference to the other answers posted, I feel you deserve to see an example of all three techniques in action. the following is highly situational, but none-the-less demonstrates what *can* happen:

**The Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>>

int i=1;

int main()
{
    printf("i=%d\n", i);

    printf("i++ : %d\n", i++);

    printf("++i : %d\n", ++i);

    i = i + 1;
    printf("i=i+1 : %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

**The Tools**

Using clang 3.3 optimization set to -O2

**The Assembly Listing**

Cleaned and annotated for consumption:

```
; Basic printf()
movl    _i(%rip), %esi
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf

; post-increment (i++)
movl    _i(%rip), %esi
leal    1(%rsi), %eax
movl    %eax, _i(%rip)
leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rdi
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf
leaq    L_.str2(%rip), %rdi

; pre-increment (++i)
movl    _i(%rip), %esi
incl    %esi
movl    %esi, _i(%rip)
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf
leaq    L_.str3(%rip), %rdi

; traditional (i = i + 1)
movl    _i(%rip), %esi
incl    %esi
movl    %esi, _i(%rip)
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf
```

**The Difference**

The stark difference is the storage of a temporary containing the prior value of `i` before increment in the case of `i++` vs `++i`. This is *solely* because said-temp is used as an argument to the `printf()` function invoke. Also note that in both the pre-increment and traditional mechanic, the resulting optimized assembly is *identical* (`movl, incl, movl`).

So does it make a difference if the post-increment operation is *not* evaluated ?

```
int main()
{
    i++;
    printf("i=%d\n", i);

    ++i;
    printf("i=%d\n", i);

    i = i + 1;
    printf("i=%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

With the resulting assembling being:

```
; post-increment
movl    _i(%rip), %esi
incl    %esi
movl    %esi, _i(%rip)
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rbx
movq    %rbx, %rdi
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf

; pre-increment
movl    _i(%rip), %esi
incl    %esi
movl    %esi, _i(%rip)
movq    %rbx, %rdi
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf

 ; traditional
movl    _i(%rip), %esi
incl    %esi
movl    %esi, _i(%rip)
movq    %rbx, %rdi
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf
```

Note that the `rbx` magic you see is unrelated and simply a way for caching the shared format string for `printf()`. In all three cases the identical code (`movl,incl,movl`) is used.

**Conclusion**

For a stand-alone statement, clang 3.3 will optimize *all three* to the same resulting code. If you introduce an evaluation dependance, post-increment and pre-increment *can* (and likely will) emit differing code. If your increment is a stand-alone statement, it makes no difference which you choose.

Comment: Very good answer. That is really the only way to settle these kind of questions. I wonder what would happen in Java (not enough to try it out though :-) )

Comment: @juanchopanza egads I'm not ashamed to say I read asm far better than jbc, and i'm *marginal* at asm, so that tells you where my jbc is =P . This thing is *highly* situational, but I just wanted to point out the behavioral differences when used in different situations. glad you approve.

Answer (score 2):

Using prefix operators is faster than using postfix. i.e `++i` is faster than `i++`.

For `++i`, the value is increased and the new value is returned.

For `i++`, the value is increased, but the old value is returned. The performance difference comes as the older value needs to be stored first.

Comment: It is like this for the postfix i.e. `i++`
Original `i` is stored 
++(*i); // call prefix operator
original `i` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the first method since I have never incremented a counter that way (I am sure someone else will come in there) but for the second it would be better to use ++i than i++. The reasons have already been answered for that one [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c), but in a nutshell, i++ makes a copy of i whereas ++i works directly on the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

`++i` is faster than other methods.

So your code will be :

```
int i = 0;
++i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Java source code:

```
    int i = 0;

    i = i + 1;

    i += 1;

    ++i;

    i++;
```

And here is the corresponding Java byte code, obtained by `javap -c`:

```
 0: iconst_0      
 1: istore_1      

 2: iload_1       
 3: iconst_1      
 4: iadd          
 5: istore_1      

 6: iinc          1, 1

 9: iinc          1, 1

12: iinc          1, 1
```

As you can see, the last three syntactic forms compile to the same JVM instruction `iinc`. The first one generates more byte code, but I'd be surprised if the JIT compiler didn't optimize that difference away.

Answer (score 0):

@Modred: For the use of two methods that you quoted the result is not the same in the case of affectaion.
for the following code the result isn't the same:

```
int i = 0, j = 0,k = 0;
cout << "i = " << i <<  " ,j = " << j << " ,k = " << k << '\n';
j = i++;
cout << "i = " << i <<  " ,j = " << j << " ,k = " << k << '\n';
k = ++i;
cout << "i = " << i <<  " ,j = " << j << " ,k = " << k << '\n';
```

**OUTPUT**

```
i = 0 ,j = 0 ,k = 0
i = 1 ,j = 0 ,k = 0
i = 2 ,j = 0 ,k = 2
```

Comment: When the pre-increment value is actually *used* for eval (such as the rhs of an assignment as you have here), then it becomes much less likely the temp will be elided. For the OP's specific stated condition, a stand-alone `j++;` vs `++j;` will result in identical asm from all but the most hideous of optimizers. Though I don't like relying on the optimizer for such things (its a crutch imho and makes for lazy engineering), they are in fact fundamentally different circumstances.