# Iterating through a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector

I'm trying to iterate through a Players hand of cards.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Card {
  int card_colour, card_type;
public:
  std::string display_card();
};

std::string Card::display_card(){
  std::stringstream s_card_details;
  s_card_details << "Colour: " << card_colour << "\n";
  s_card_details << "Type: " << card_type << "\n";
    
  return s_card_details.str();
}

int main() 
{
  std::vector<Card*>current_cards;
  vector<Card*>::iterator iter;
  for(iter = current_cards.begin(); iter != current_cards.end(); iter++) 
  {
    std::cout << iter->display_card() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This line

```
std::cout << iter->display_card() << std::endl;
```

currently comes up with the

> error: Expression must have pointer-to-class type.

How can I fix this?

Comment: That error message sounds backwards.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
cout << (*iter)->display_card() << endl;
```

The `*` operator gives you the item referenced by the iterator, which in your case is a pointer. Then you use the `->` to dereference that pointer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to dereference the iterator to access the pointer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Card {
public:
  std::string display_card();
};


int main() {
  std::vector<Card*>current_cards;
  std::vector<Card*>::iterator iter, end;
  for(iter = current_cards.begin(), end = current_cards.end() ; iter != end; ++iter) {
    std::cout << (*iter)->display_card() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Another observation is the `iter++` which you should avoid in profit of `++iter` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904/2077394).
Depending on the container, you may also want to avoid calling `end()` each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

De-referencing the iterator by `iter->` gives a pointer to an object of type `Card`, you have to write `(*iter)->display_card();`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `(*iter)->` is to pre-emptively dereference the iterator with [range-based for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

```
std::vector<Card*> current_cards;
// Code that populates current_cards goes here...

for(auto p_card : current_cards)
{
    std::cout << p_card->display_card() << std::endl;
}
```

In the above code, `p_card` is already a `Card*` pointer instead of a `std::vector<Card*>::iterator` iterator. To me this is clearer than the version that explicitly dereferences the iterator and then dereferences the pointer, and is certainly more concise. It also means I don't have to worry about operator precedence pitfalls with `->` and unary `*`.