# c++ function to check if a number is a prime

Tags: c++, primes, time-limiting

```
bool prime (long long int n) {
    bool prime = 1;
    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        for (long long int i = 2; i <= n/2 ; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                prime = 0;
                break ;
            }
            
        }
        return prime;
    }
}
```

This is my function to check if `n` is a prime or not. It works until I try a number with 12 digits, like n = 999999999989.

This is for a [problem on codeforces](https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/223338/problem/B); when I submit this function the website prints "Time limit exceeded".

Comment: You only have to check up to the square root of the number.  q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101217/4641116

Comment: `bool prime = 1;`? Is `true` and `false` out of fashion?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @AlanBirtles A sieve is not helpful if your task is to check primality of a single number.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Rather this direction: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code's time complexity is O(n/2) -> O(n).
It would take around 10000 second to check the primality of n if n is 10^12 (given 1 second can only do around 10^8 operation).

```
for (long long int i = 2; i <= n/2 ; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        prime = 0;
        break ;
}
```

The trick here is that you don't need to check i from 2 to n/2. Instead, you can reduce it to just from 2 to sqrt(n). This work because since sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) is n, there shouldn't be any x and y so that x > sqrt(n); y > sqrt(n); x*y = n. Thus, if a divisor for n exist, it should be <= sqrt(n).

So you should change your loop to this

```
for (long long int i = 2; i*i <= n ; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        prime = 0;
        break ;
    }
}
```

The time complexity for this code is O(sqrt(n)) which should be enough for n
= 10^12.

P.S : sqrt(n) means square root of n

Comment: you don't need to check the even numbers (apart from 2)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Actually you only need to check primes. (That can be arranged with a bit of recursion. ) Some folk question the purity of skipping evens - as you're sort of "hard coding" that.

Comment: Note that `i <= n / i` is a better way of writing the stopping conditional as it avoids a potential overflow of an integral type. Nice answer though. Have an upvote.

Comment: @AlanBirtles You're right. But I don't think it really impact much on the time complexity

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah You're also right, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It'll make it twice as fast...

Comment: @AlanBirtles - perhaps. Or you could get the compiler to calculate them - so O(1) at runtime.

Comment: Speaking of code optimizations: do **not** use the post-increment operator (`i++`) in a for loop. 
The post-increment operator [creates a temporary copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941980/why-post-increment-needs-to-make-a-copy-while-pre-increment-does-not) that's not needed here. 
So, just stick to the pre-increment operator `++i`.