# What i am doing wrong in erasing some vector elements?

Tags: c++, string, vector

Here i am trying to print the frequency of each word in the sentence, which is stored in the `vector` of `string`

```
void display_by_word (vector<string> vs) //pass by value is necessary because we need to delete the elements.
{
vector<string> :: size_type vec_size, i;
string to_cmp = vs[0];
int occ = 0;

for ( i = 0; i < vs.size(); ++i){

    vector <string> :: iterator it = vs.begin() + 1;
    occ = 1;

    for ( it ; it != vs.end(); ++it){

        if ( vs[i] == *it){

            vs.erase(it);
            occ++;
        }
    }

    cout << vs[i] << "     " << occ << endl;
}

}
```

Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it crashes.what is wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: shouldn't it be like `it=vs.erase(it);`?

Comment: @paper.plane what good it will do for me as i am still incrementing the iterator?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight is it more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to rewrite the loop as something like this

```
while(it != vs.end())
{
    if ( vs[i] == *it){

        it = vs.erase(it);
        occ++;
    }
    else
        it++;
}
```

Comment: when we erase any element is it necessary that every time new memory would be allocated for the remaining vector or adjustment can be made at the current memory?

Comment: You should prefer `++it;`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Answer (score 3):

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase [...]

After the `erase` has happened, you cannot reuse `it` because it has been invalidated. It's undefined behaviour, which can include random crashes.

However, `erase` returns an iterator to the element following the erased one, or to `end()` if it was the last element, which is why the solution with `it = vs.erase(it);` works.

Alternatively, consider using [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), followed by the two-argument `erase`, which is known as the [Erase-Remove Idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove). It may turn out to be more elegant and more readable than a hand-written loop. Or just rewrite the whole function to use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Answer (score 1):

You may should do as below:
`
for ( it ; it != vs.end(); ){

```
    if ( vs[i] == *it){

        it = vs.erase(it);
        occ++;
    }
    else{
        ++it;
    }
}
```

`