# C++ Join multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I would like to do a for-loop which creates more threads.

I've tried with:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    thread t1(nThre);
    t1.join();
    cout << "Joined thread n'" << i << '\n';
}
```

But it does not work. `nThre` is called sequentially (it is a simple `void` routine).

I'm also asking if I can use a pre-increment as `i` is just an `int`, so:
`++i` insted of `i++`, which should be more performant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you start a thread, and join it before starting the next one. You should do like this :

```
int i;
vector<thread> threads;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threads.push_back(thread(nThre));
    cout << "Started thread n'" << i << "\n";
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
    cout << "Joined thread n'" << i << "\n";
}
```

First, you start all your threads, then you wait until they are finished.

For the difference between `i++` and `++i`, since `i` is a integer, it makes no difference here. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c#answer-24904) for more details.

Comment: As a general rule you should use prefix, except when you need postfix.