# Accessing a size_type of vector inside a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have got a structure

```
struct str{
 std::vector<double> values;
};
```

And I have got a for loop in my program that interates through values in this vector and these codes work:

```
str s;
for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < s.values.size(); i++) {
```

and

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < s.values.size(); i++) {
```

but I know that it should be done somehow like here but I have got an error. How to get this size?

```
for (str::values::size_type i = 0; i < s.values.size(); i++) {
```

And I know that I could use

```
for (auto i : str.values)
```

but I also need number of iteration, not only `double` value that is in that `vector`. Is it possible using this solution?

Comment: What is a `structue`?

Comment: sorry, a typo, I meant struct

Comment: Well, that's one problem fixed. There's a missing semicolon after the `struct` definition, `str.values` is incorrect. Try to compile your example before posting it.

Comment: ok, that is just a part of my code.. struct is bigger and has got more variables but I just wanted to show what I mean

Comment: It is definitely MUCH easier to answer questions that have complete code - because you don't have to guess what the "skipped over bits" are, or whether the answer will work for those parts - and one can also, usually figure out more what it's meant to do if it's a complete example.

Comment: The type of `values` is `std::vector<double>`. The fact that it's in a struct is irrelevant. The statement "I know it should be done ..." is wrong. You're looking for `std::vector<double>::size_type` -- which or already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to mix type declarations and variables.

You probably need some kind of `using` or `typedef` [or `decltype` as the other answer says] to avoid having to know what `values` is.

This compiles:

```
#include <vector>
struct str{
    using Storage = std::vector<double>;
    Storage values;
};

int main()
{
    str s;
    for(str::Storage::size_type i = 0; i < s.values.size(); i++)
    {
    }
}
```

As does this:

```
#include <vector>

struct str{
    typedef std::vector<double>::size_type size_type;
    std::vector<double> values;
};

int main()
{
    str s;
    for(str::size_type i = 0; i < s.values.size(); i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `decltype`

```
str s;
for (decltype(str::values)::size_type i = 0; i < s.values.size(); ++i)
{}
```

Comment: Then I have got an error : "Field values must be static"

Comment: Could I ask why have you used ++i? I see it very often in for loops that iterate thru vectors. Actually I need indexes from 0 to size-1

Comment: @Mateusz What compiler and version are you using? The code above [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4e3da6df1cd3103). Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24901/241631) for pre increment vs post increment.

Comment: g++, yeah it compiles but Clion underslines everything after this for loop and shows popup that it is wrong O.o

Comment: @Mateusz I've never used Clion so I can't help with that problem. But make sure its parser is being invoked in C++11 mode. If that's already the case, then you may have found a bug in the IDE's parser.