# What is the proper way to remove items from a List<WeakReference<T>>?

Tags: c#, weak-references

Is the following loop approach, using TryGetTarget then compare the proper way?

```
void Remove<T>( List<WeakReference<T>> list, T toRemove ) where T : class {
    for(var i=0; i<list.Count; ++i) {
        if(list[i].TryGetTarget(out var el) && el==toRemove) {
            list.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant or suggested way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any particular concern about that approach?

Comment: Just want to see if there is more elegant way.

Comment: Seems correct here. The `++i` is quite ugly and is very old school (when `++i` was waster than `i++`, [but only for specific advanced cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c))

Comment: Are you certain that there'll only be one such reference, or that you only wish to remove one? Otherwise, `list.RemoveAll(wr => wr.TryGetTarget(out var el) && el == toRemove)` would work well too.

Comment: @xanatos yeah, old c++ habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably shorten it to:

```
list.RemoveAll(item => item.TryGetTarget(out var el) && el == toRemove);
```

Comment: There is a difference here... `RemoveAll` will look at duplicates (so it will parse all the elements), he is doing a "`RemoveFirst`".

Comment: I was just adding a comment adding the same thing. It behaves slightly differently though: 1) it may remove more than one item; 2) it won't stop when it's found the first item, potentially causing a difference in performance.

Comment: hm, true, I figured that "Remove items" in the headline meant that actually removing those items is the goal... Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: Actually the code is for demo. I want see if it is suggested to use a TryGetTarget then compare or something like ReferenceEquals. May be I am not clear.

Comment: @somebody4 If T is a reference, then `==` is converted to `ReferenceEquals`. Compare on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgNwFgBQMDMSBMCAwggN5YKVJ4BGA9nRAgLLIA8AKgHwAUHCAQ2QAaBPwH4AlAgDuACwCmAJwViEIAmQpUdMAOwI6NAFYKAxsAB0AJQUAzZQoB2ZhQFEAjgFcBEAM48QqISkhiYOgC+WNqUuAj0jCz4nLziImohsooqahowhOThOlT6gsgIALwVgvhhkVgRQA==) the IL Code