# ++i vs i++ ? Why is i++ faster while ++i is supposed to be faster?

Tags: c++

++i is supposed to be faster than i++ right?? Then why this o/p ??
Below is the code in CPP

```
start = clock();
srand(time(NULL));

cout<<"++i"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i!=-1;++i);

end = clock();
total_time = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout<<"Time taken for ++i : "<<total_time<<"\n\n";

start = clock();
srand(time(NULL));

cout<<"i++"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i!=-1;i++);

end = clock();
total_time = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout<<"Time taken for i++ : "<<total_time<<endl;
```

And this is the output

> ++i Time taken for ++i : 12.2812
>
> i++ Time taken for i++ : 12.125

Comment: *"++i is supposed to be faster than i++ right?"* - That argument doesn't apply to primitive types like `int`. Only user defined types. And the argument is that it can (should?) never be slower than, not that it is always faster than.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c)

Comment: Try to implement them and you will understand why it should be faster. Also, use a high resolution clock and compile without optimizations.

Comment: @ZDF **with** optimizations?

Comment: First of all: overflowing signed integers is an undefined behaviour. Secondly: any sane compiler will produce the same assembly for your code (which you can check here: https://godbolt.org/z/esZ0PR ). Thirdly: compilers may and will optimize out dummy loops like yours when optimizations are enabled, your code is flawed. Finally: you are measuring clock ticks. It is the smallest unit of time recognizable by a device. Ergo everything after `.` is a approximation noise.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Without.

Comment: @ZDF But speed measurements without optimization are nonsense. Why would you measure unoptimized binaries?!?!

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Read Batsheba's answer below.

Comment: @ZDF Batsheba is right: for speed measurements you have to write code that cannot be optimized away by the compiler. Still, you never want to measure unoptimized binaries. Otherwise the numbers just have no useful meaning!

Comment: @BenjaminBihler The question is "Why...".

Comment: @ZDF Because most probably you will compile your software in release mode with optimizations turned on while deploying it. Therefore this performance is important and not the performance in debug mode during the development phase.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed conceptually at least `++i` will never be slower than `i++` due to the latter somehow storing the original value for later return.

But you are forgetting an important concept: the *as-if* rule. All modern compilers will optimise `++i` and `i++` to the same thing.

Note furthermore that a good compiler will optimise the *undefined* statement (due to `int` overflow) `for(int i=0;i!=-1;++i);` to a no-op. Many would also do so if `i` was an `unsigned` type. This is because its inclusion or otherwise has no effect on the program.

Answer (score 0):

`clock ()` method is not a good way to calculate the time difference

maybe you can use

```
high_resolution_clock::now()
```

Comment: While helpful that's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: thank you for your warning. i am newbei for stackoverflow

Comment: You can read on further about [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).