# Incrementing in for loop condition

Tags: c, performance, for-loop

While browsing the Linux source code, I came across the following [line](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/98d54f81e36ba3bf92172791eba5ca5bd813989b/kernel/pid.c#L343):

```
int tmp;    
for (tmp = PIDTYPE_MAX; --tmp >= 0; )
```

Why not do:

```
for (tmp = PIDTYPE_MAX; tmp >= 0; tmp--)
```

Is this [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) sort of for loop optimization?

Comment: Your loops are not equivalent. By decrementing the iterator variable before the loop body ensures that the condition `0 <= tmp < PIDTYPE_MAX` is always true. This is in fact the canonical backwards loop in C, where lower bounds are inclusive and upper bound are exclusive. (But I'd prefer `tmp-- > 0`, which works with unsigned types as well.)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I'd be happy to mark it as an answer if you change your comment to an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loops are not equivalent: The second loop includes the upper bound `PIDTYPE_MAX`, the first one doesn't.

Decrementing the iterator variable before the loop body ensures that the condition `0 <= tmp < PIDTYPE_MAX` is always true in the loop. This is in fact the canonical backwards loop in C, where lower bounds are inclusive and upper bound are exclusive.

Note that the first loop requires a signed integer to work, so that the test for `tmp >= 0` makes sense. (It would always be true for unsigned integers.)

Unsigned types like `size_t` are often used for array indices and counts, which cannot be negative. The respective loops are:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) ...     // iterate over [0, N) forwards
for (size_t i = N; i-- > 0; ) ...      // iterate over [0, N) backwards
```

Answer (score 0):

In first case the value of temp will be decremented before entering into the loop. While in second case the value of temp will be decremented after execution of loop body.