# C++: list iterators vs. vector iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I thought the idea of the iterator object was that you can apply it similarly to the C++ container classes. When I try to iterate through a list object, however, I tried using

```
for(list<int>::iterator it = obj.begin(); it < obj.end(); it++){
    // some code
}
```

And I got an error. Why doesn't this work? Why would it work for `vector::iterator`? Is it just because of the implementation of list being bi-directional linked lists? I thought the iterator object abstracts that notion of moving through containers, thereby allowing it to operationally be the same, whether for vectors or lists.

I'd really appreciate a clarification.

Comment: it < obj.end() should be it != obj.end(), Also do not use it++, use ++it(more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077026/incrementing-iterators-it-more-efficient-than-it)) and use non-member begin and end if you use c++11... and maybe you don't want end function to be called every time...

Comment: What error? Does the compiler tell you anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not work because, unlike `std::vector` iterators, `std::list` iterators are not random-access - they are sequential. You need to use `!=` on them:

```
for(list<int>::iterator it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); it++)
```

In general, it's a good idea to use "not equals" on all iterators when you are looking to cover the entire range, even when these iterators allow comparisons for `<` and `>`. There is also an argument in favor of using `!=` in your regular `for` loops, too, because it gives you the strongest [*postcondition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition).

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare with `!=` as list iterators are scattered throughout all memory in random order.

Use: `for(list<int>::iterator it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); it++)`

Answer (score 0):

That's because `list` does not support *random access* iterators, but only *forward* iterators. Therefore, `operator <` is not defined for iterators of a `list`. You have to use `operator !=` for inequality comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Operator arithmetic, including ordering-comparison operators (like `<`), is only defined for random access iterators. If you change the code to use `!=`, it will work (assuming `obj` is a `list<int>`):

```
for(list<int>::iterator it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); it++){
    // some code
}
```