# no known conversion from 'const value_type' to 'const void *' for 1st argument

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, c++14

I'm trying to print a set of pairs using std::cout, but it's not compiling. I'm using C++14 on XCode 9. The error occurs on `cout<<(*it);` line

Error: Invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'const value_type' (aka 'const std::__1::pair'))

Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const value_type' (aka 'const std::__1::pair') to 'const void *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

template <class P, class Q> ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, pair<P,Q>& p)
{
    cout<<"["<<p.first<<","<<p.second<<"]";
    return out;
}

template <class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, set<T> &S)
{
    cout<<"{";
    for(typename set<T>::iterator it = S.begin(); it != S.end(); it++) {
        cout<<(*it);   //Error occurs here
        if(next(it,1) != S.end()) cout<<",";
    }
    cout<<"}";
    return out;
}

int main() {
    set<pair<int,int>> s;
    s.insert({1,2});
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your overload should take `std::pair` by **const** reference. (same for `std::set`)

Comment: Also, use `++it` instead of `it++` in the loop.

Comment: Thank you! And could you tell me the difference ++it and it++ makes? For integers I've always been using postfix increments.

Comment: @PrayanshSrivastava See, e.g., here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077026/580083

Comment: For explanation, non-const lvalue references may be bound only to non-const lvalues. Const lvalue references may be bound to both const and non-const lvalues and rvalues. Since you do not modify referenced objects in operator<<, there is no reason why not to use const reference.

Comment: @DanielLangr: or use for range: `cout << "{"; auto sep = ""; for (const auto& e : S) { cout << sep << e; sep = ","; } cout "}";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterator of `std::set` is a constant bidirectional iterator (at least starting from C++11). Its dereferencing therefore result in a constant reference to set element/key (you may not modify set keys directly, which makes sense, since it would break the underlying data structure - usually some form of search tree). This reference represents a constant lvalue argument, which may not be bound to parameter of non-const reference type (`p` in `operator<<`). As others already suggested, use `const` references as parameters instead.