# Faster form for hamming distance in c++ (potentially taking advantage of standard library)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, stl

I have two `int` `vectors` like `a[100]`, `b[100]`.
The simple way to calculate their hamming distance  is:

```
std::vector<int> a(100);
std::vector<int> b(100);

double dist = 0;    
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if(a[i] != b[i])
        dist++;
}
dist /= a.size();
```

I would like to ask that is there a faster way to do this calculation in C++ or how to use STL to do the same job?

Comment: The best answer is simply to replace `if(a[i] != b[i]) dist++;` with `disti += (a[i] != b[i])`

Answer (score 5):

You asked for a faster way. This is a [embarrassingly parallel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), so, with C++ you can take advantage of that in two ways: thread parallelism, and vectorization through optimization.

```
//The following flags allow cpu specific vectorization optimizations on *my cpu*
//clang++ -march=corei7-avx hd.cpp -o hd -Ofast -pthread -std=c++1y
//g++ -march=corei7-avx hd.cpp -o hd -Ofast -pthread -std=c++1y

#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <numeric>

template<class T, class I1, class I2>
T hamming_distance(size_t size, I1 b1, I2 b2) {
    return std::inner_product(b1, b1 + size, b2, T{},
            std::plus<T>(), std::not_equal_to<T>());
}

template<class T, class I1, class I2>
T parallel_hamming_distance(size_t threads, size_t size, I1 b1, I2 b2) {
    if(size < 1000)
       return hamming_distance<T, I1, I2>(size, b1, b2);

    if(threads > size)
        threads = size;

    const size_t whole_part = size / threads;
    const size_t remainder = size - threads * whole_part;

    std::vector<std::future<T>> bag;
    bag.reserve(threads + (remainder > 0 ? 1 : 0));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
        bag.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async,
                            hamming_distance<T, I1, I2>,
                            whole_part,
                            b1 + i * whole_part,
                            b2 + i * whole_part));
    if(remainder > 0)
        bag.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async,
                            hamming_distance<T, I1, I2>,
                            remainder,
                            b1 + threads * whole_part,
                            b2 + threads * whole_part));

    T hamming_distance = 0;
    for(auto &f : bag) hamming_distance += f.get();
    return hamming_distance;
}

#include <ratio>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> random_0_9(0, 9);

    const auto size = 100 * mega::num;
    vector<int32_t> v1(size);
    vector<int32_t> v2(size);

    for(auto &x : v1) x = random_0_9(gen);
    for(auto &x : v2) x = random_0_9(gen);

    cout << "naive hamming distance: ";
    const auto naive_start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << hamming_distance<int32_t>(v1.size(), begin(v1), begin(v2)) << endl;
    const auto naive_elapsed = high_resolution_clock::now() - naive_start;

    const auto n = thread::hardware_concurrency();

    cout << "parallel hamming distance: ";
    const auto parallel_start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << parallel_hamming_distance<int32_t>(
                                                    n,
                                                    v1.size(),
                                                    begin(v1),
                                                    begin(v2)
                                              )
         << endl;
    const auto parallel_elapsed = high_resolution_clock::now() - parallel_start;

    auto count_microseconds =
        [](const high_resolution_clock::duration &elapsed) {
            return duration_cast<microseconds>(elapsed).count();
        };

    cout << "naive delay:    " << count_microseconds(naive_elapsed) << endl;
    cout << "parallel delay: " << count_microseconds(parallel_elapsed) << endl;
}
```

*notice that I'm not taking the division over the vector size*

**Results for my machine** (which shows it didn't get much for a machine which only 2 physical cores...):

```
$ clang++ -march=corei7-avx hd.cpp -o hd -Ofast -pthread -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -lcxxrt -ldl
$ ./hd
naive hamming distance: 89995190
parallel hamming distance: 89995190
naive delay:    52758
parallel delay: 47227

$ clang++ hd.cpp -o hd -O3 -pthread -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -lcxxrt -ldl
$ ./hd
naive hamming distance: 90001042
parallel hamming distance: 90001042
naive delay:    53851
parallel delay: 46887

$ g++ -march=corei7-avx hd.cpp -o hd -Ofast -pthread -std=c++1y -Wl,--no-as-needed
$ ./hd
naive hamming distance: 90001825
parallel hamming distance: 90001825
naive delay:    55229
parallel delay: 49355

$ g++ hd.cpp -o hd -O3 -pthread -std=c++1y -Wl,--no-as-needed
$ ./hd
naive hamming distance: 89996171
parallel hamming distance: 89996171
naive delay:    54189
parallel delay: 44928
```

Also I see no effect from auto vectorization, may have to check the assembly...

For a sample about vectorization and compiler options check this [blog post of mine](http://nosubstance.me/articles/2013-10-11-yeppp-a-trivial-test/).

Comment: This is the correct answer, the one accepted above is incorrect.

Comment: I get a huge boost from auto vectorization as well as using multiple threads.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple way to optimize this.

```
int disti = 0;    
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) disti += (a[i] != b[i]);
double dist = 1.0*disti/a.size();
```

This skips the branch and uses the virtue that a conditional test returns 1 or 0.  Additionally, it is auto-vectorized in GCC (`-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1` to check) while the version in the question is not.

**Edit:**

I went ahead and tested this out with the function in the question which I called `hamming_distance` the simple fix I suggested which I call `hamming_distance_fix` and a version which uses the fix as well as OpenMP which I call `hamming_distance_fix_omp`.  Here are the times

```
hamming_distance          1.71 seconds
hamming_distance_fix      0.38 seconds  //SIMD
hamming_distance_fix_omp  0.12 seconds  //SIMD + MIMD
```

Here is the code.  I did not use much syntactic candy but it should be very easy to convert this to use STL and so forth...You can see the results here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31293bc88cff4794

```
//g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O3 -fopenmp -msse2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

double hamming_distance(int* a, int*b, int n) {
    double dist = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) dist++;
    }
    return dist/n;
}
double hamming_distance_fix(int* a, int* b, int n) {
    int disti = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
       disti += (a[i] != b[i]);
    }
    return 1.0*disti/n;
}

double hamming_distance_fix_omp(int* a, int* b, int n) {
    int disti = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:disti)
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
       disti += (a[i] != b[i]);
    }
    return 1.0*disti/n;
}

int main() {
    const int n = 1<<16;
    const int repeat = 10000;
    int *a = new int[n];
    int *b = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        a[i] = rand()%10;
        b[i] = rand()%10;
    }

    double dtime, dist;
    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++) dist = hamming_distance(a,b,n);
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("dist %f, time (s) %f\n", dist, dtime);

    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++) dist = hamming_distance_fix(a,b,n);
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("dist %f, time (s) %f\n", dist, dtime);

    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++) dist = hamming_distance_fix_omp(a,b,n);
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("dist %f, time (s) %f\n", dist, dtime);  
}
```

Comment: Would changing `i++` into `++i` have much impact on performance?

Comment: @Dharman, no. That only makes a difference for some C++ objects, not for POD floats and ints. You can find answers for that on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561588/what-is-more-efficient-i-or-i/561609#561609) if you search. Also, if you need to micro tune then you should always look at the assembly anyway and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As an observation, working with double is **very** slow, even for increment. so you should use a int inside the `for` (incrementing), and then use a double for the division.

As a speed up, one way to test I could think of is to use SSE instructions:

Pseudocode:

```
distance = 0
SSE register e1
SSE register e2
for each 4 elements in vectors
  load 4 members from a in e1
  load 4 members from b in e2
  if e1 == e2
    continue
  else
    check each 4 members individually (using e1 and e2)
dist /= 4
```

In a real (not-pseudocode) program, this can be twitched so that the compiler can use `cmov` instructions instead of `branches`.

The main advantage here is that we have 4 times less reads from memory.
A disadvantage is that we have an extra check for each 4 checks we had previously.
Depending on how this gets implemented in assembly via `cmoves` or `branches`, this might be even faster for vectors that have many adjacent positions with the same value in the two vectors.

I really can't tell how this will perform comparing with the standard solution, but at the very least is worth testing.

Comment: That is a lot of loading/storing for a single comparison.  Not convinced that in the average case using SSE here would actually give you a performance boost, at least not with this simple an implementation.

Comment: @Andrey when I say "check each 4 members individually" I mean through `e1` and `e2`, not loading again from memory.