# Why does `--var` and `var-1` work differently?

Tags: java, pre-increment

I did write a code to print all valid combinations of n-pair parentheses. However, at my first try, the algorithm output all the combinations twice, that is, . The code was:

```
public static void solve(char[] string, int open, int closed, int index)
{
    if (open < 0 || closed < open) {
        return;
    }

    if (open == 0 && closed == 0) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    if (open > 0) {
        string[index] = '(';
        solve(string, --open, closed, ++index);
    }

    if (closed > open) {
        string[index] = ')';
        solve(string, open, --closed, ++index);
    }
}
```

I spend a significant amount of time in order to see what went wrong. I figured the code went into the last if branch more than it should. Then, while trying different things, I realized 
changing

```
solve(string, --open, closed, ++index);
```

to

```
solve(string, open-1, closed, ++index);
```

changed the outcome. This resulted in getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Finally, I replaced all pre-increment operations with corresponding arithmetic operations(e.g., `++index` to `index+1`) and the code ran correctly.

My question is, shouldn't `--open` and `open-1` calculate and send the same value as parameter to the function? How come the code behaves differently when they should calculate the same value?

Comment: `--foo` changes the value of `foo`; `foo-1` does not.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561588/what-is-more-efficient-i-or-i

Comment: Another thing to spot is that more than one of your if sections can run because you haven't used elseif

Comment: Yeah exactly! I just assumed I was else-ing the second part. That's why I missed the side-effect!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
solve(string, --open, closed, ++index);
```

actually changes `open` to be one less than before, which makes the next use of `open` just below act on a value 1 less than passed in.

```
solve(string, open-1, closed, ++index);
```

...on the other hand passes `open-1` into the solve method, but does *not* change `open`, so it's used unchanged when used in later statements.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `--x` is a pre decrement operation which will always be same as `x=x-1;`

ie decrement x by 1 first and then assign decremented value of x to x.

so x value will definitely changes when we perform `--x`.

but `x-1` is just an operation we are doing on x and operation is subtract.

here we are assigning this result into some argument in the method which is receiving this call. but its not reassigned to x automatically.

so `x-1` is never ever equals `x=x-1;` and hence x remains same, only receiver gets subtracted value.

hence

```
solve(string, --open, closed, ++index);
```

in the above statement , pre decrement is performed on `open`.

so it is same as `open=open-1;` and hence open value changed.

but

```
solve(string, open-1, closed, ++index);
```

above statement is subtracting 1 from `open` and passing subtratced value to method.

its same as `receiveing_variable_in_method_definition = open-1` but open is not changing.