# Why is prefix incrementation (++x) faster than postfix incrementation (x++) in C?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c)

I heard it said that prefix incrementation is faster than postfix incrementation in C. Is this true and why?

++x vs x++

Comment: It's not. Title of question should be changed to reflect this...

Comment: The "why" in the title got me excited since I was expecting benchmarks... what a letdown...

Comment: Don't believe everything you hear.

Comment: not only possible, it's EXACT DUPLICATE.

Comment: Somehow fast as ++x when apply increment the value but x++ don't increment on same line so It make a extra copy and then increment the value to next line....so x++ is overhead by extra copy that why performance is somehow slower than ++x

Comment: Might want to modify the duplicate so that it says prefix and postfix increment to help in search results. I wouldn't of posted this is the search found the duplicate for me (the duplicate is ambiguous)

Comment: @EhevuTov Don't modify the duplicate. That's the whole point of keeping questions like this closed (but undeleted) - so that they serve as sign-posts to the original with different titles.

Comment: @Mysticial ah, links...I see what you did there

Answer (score 2):

Short answer no. Reason is that it's the same operation, just the order of evaluation of the statement is changed.

Example:

```
int a = x++;
int b = ++x;
```

Pseudo assembly:

```
mov a, x
inc x
inc x
mov b, x
```

This is a trivial example but even in larger examples the worst that can happen is a memory barrier enforced operation which doesn't allow the post increment value to be pushed or pulled past it which just adds an extra `mov` operation due to a dependency or forced barrier. Most compilers optimize away this extra `mov` in standard situations anyway using instruction reordering.

Answer (score 2):

This is a ridiculous myth that gets repeated over and over. The two operators have *semantic* differences; one has as its result the old value and the other has as the result its new value. If you use this result, the code will have different behavior depending on which operator you used, and this may include performance differences if one behavior can be achieved more efficiently than the other. But if you don't use the result, `x=x+1`, `x+=1`, `x++`, and `++x` are all **identical**.

Comment: There were some exceptions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c?rq=1 such as a C80 compiler.