# Why is the postfix increment faster than the prefix one in the C++?

Tags: c++

I thought always, that it must be conversely. But when I tried this simple code, I got unexpected results:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  double z;
  chrono::steady_clock::time_point start_point;

  start_point = chrono::steady_clock::now();

  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; x = ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < 100000; y = ++j)
      z = static_cast<double>(x * y);

  cout << "The prefix increment took a " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start_point).count() << " milliseconds" << endl;

  start_point = chrono::steady_clock::now();

  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; x = i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 100000; y = j++)
      z = static_cast<double>(x * y);

  cout << "The postfix increment took a " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start_point).count() << " milliseconds" << endl;

  // To make the compiler happy...
  x = y = static_cast<int>(z / z);

  cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The result of running of this code at my machine is:

```
The prefix increment took a 25716 milliseconds
The postfix increment took a 19119 milliseconds
SUCCESS
```

**EDIT:**

Yep, changing the `z = ...` to the `z += ...` leaded to that the execution times became equal.

So thank all of you for your answers.

Comment: You weren't "compelled" to place dummy text. You were notified there is not much of an explanation present. You *chose* to post dummy text to circumvent that.

Comment: My guess is that the second run is always faster than the first run.

Comment: maybe related (C): https://stackoverflow.com/q/12190624/1132334

Comment: You should at least isolate the time calculation so you're sure that you're not measuring the output time.

Comment: Micro-benchmarking things like that is notoriously difficult.

Comment: The rule that prefix increment is faster only holds for proper objects were the postfix increment is implemented in terms of the prefix one. Int is a fundamental type and thus this rule does not apply here.

Comment: I'm skeptical. Compilation flags please?

Comment: You could "_make the compiler happy_" by declaring x, y and z volatile.  What compiler, platform and build options have you used - that information may be necessary to replicate your result.  I would advise observing the disassembly of this code (in your debugger for example).  That may answer your question.

Comment: I get similar numbers with this code. The numbers don't change much when running the postfix version first. The optimized version takes no time at all.

Comment: Option 1/ optimization is disabled => your test is meaningless. Option 2/ optimization is enabled => loops are optimized away => your test is meaningless.

Comment: very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Comment: Optimisations was turned off. Changing the order does not give anything. If I try to make this numbers in the cycles greater, then times grows too (it's about of time measuring; e.g., I got something about 103 seconds vs 70 seconds; so I think this is not a measuring error).

Comment: @SergeRoussak Change `z =` to `z +=`, otherwise, the compiler can completely optimize away the loops. Print out `z` after the loops. Turn on optimizations. Boht loops then take almost the same time: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jb1lFEvx1kpRcbHh

Comment: Not only is this architecture dependant - but also compiler dependant.  How do you know that on platform X the way to do an i++ can't be taken down to a single instruction while ++i is 400.

Comment: When I run your code I get both of them coming in right at 0 ms.  You're not benchmarking un-optimized code are you?

Comment: @xaxxon He's already said in the comments that yes, this is unoptimised.  (Sadly he didn't update the question)

Comment: @xaxxon, you compiled with full optimisation, that's why you have got, what you have got.

Comment: @UKMonkey Oh, sorry.   I thought this was still an active question, but it seems like it's been solved.

Comment: @SergeRoussak of course I did.   It doesn't make any sense to time any other builds.  That's why the results you got are meaningless.

Comment: @SergeRoussak - And the fact you *haven't* compiled with optimizations makes your testing nonsensical, frankly.

Comment: @xaxxon don't say sorry - Question is missing a huge amount of information in it. :)

Comment: But this all said, although the OP is being, let's say, a little forthright, that doesn't make this a poor question. It's still well-presented with compilable code (however flawed), and documented output. +1 and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 15):

There is no difference at all - any perceived difference is due to artifacts introduced by your testing technique.

Compilers have been optimising away `i++` for years now (although I still use `++i` out of habit). Don't test things like this - setting up a framework is too difficult. Trivialise the program and check the generated assembly instead.

Note also that on a platform with a 32 bit `int` (very common) the behaviour of your code is undefined due to `int` overflow (`100,000` squared is larger than the 31<sup>st</sup> power of 2). This renders your testing *completely* useless.

Comment: Really?.. Do you think that 30 seconds (see my comment) are "no difference"?

Comment: @SergeRoussak: Yes your testing is baseless. Why do you continue to persist with this notion that you're correct and have made a discovery that i++ is faster than ++i? Come on, be serious!

Comment: @SergeRoussak  when I run your code I get them both taking 0 ms.  Your testing is wrong.

Comment: @Bathsheba, 'cause I tested it with the same compiler, at the same platform etc... (The source is placed in the same translation unit, so two cycles can not be executed in the different conditions). If someone say that compilers optimize out the difference between such using of this operators, then we could expect an equal times of execution. But WHY one cycle runs slower approximately by 30% than other one does?

Comment: Hints: (1) fix the UB, (2) `cout << "The prefix increment took a " ` introduces *a lot* of overhead. (3) Do more with each value of x and y: perhaps *sum* them to `z`? (4) Copy out your two loops multiple times. (5) Switch the order of the runs.

Comment: @SergeRoussak compiler optimize in *optimized* builds, not in *unoptimized* builds - since you clearly told the compiler not to optimize the code, why do you expect it to optimize it anyway?

Answer (score 7):

Adding only few to what [Bathsheba has already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507786/7571171), both

```
int i;
i++
```

and

```
int i;
++i
```

get compiled to

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
```

where the important line incrementing the value is

```
add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
^^^                   ^^^
relevant             parts
```

---

In answer to your comment regarding optimizations, above code was with optimizations **off**; using `-O` leads to

```
add DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
^^^                 ^^^
relevant           parts
```

for both `i++` and `++i`.
I had to adjust the sample to

```
void F(int& i)
{
    ++i; // respectively i++
}
```

for it to be not optimized away totally, but the point is still the same.

---

I used `gcc 7.3 x86-64`. Test it yourself using the [Online Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: This is convincing (+1), but do mention the compiler specifics and target architecture here.

Comment: @Bathsheba thank you for your feedback, I edited the answer now to address both your feedback and OP's statement about optimizations.

Comment: And do feel free to complete this answer by mentioning the UB in the code.

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry, what do you mean by *"UB"*? Undefined behavior?

Comment: Absolutely͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏