# it adds a second } and does not add 1 to the level

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, math

It keeps adding an extra } to the json file and wont add 1 to the level

I have tried to have it saving the original level value to a txt file then waiting a second then adding 1 to it.

```
    if(xpout > 100) {
        var lvupxp = xp.xp - 100
        var expcontent = `{ "xp": ${lvupxp}, "level": ${xp.level++} }`
        var exppath = `./Users/${message.author.username}/xp.json`;
        fs.writeFile(exppath, expcontent, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        })

    }
```

{ "xp": 7, "level": 0 } }

Comment: [I can't reproduce that extra brace](https://jsfiddle.net/2cthesg1/). But if you want to increase the level use the prefix `++xp.level` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `level` property to contain the incremented level, you have to use pre-increment, not post-increment. See [++ operator returns original value if placed after operand — how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864091/operator-returns-original-value-if-placed-after-operand-how/13864160#13864160)

Also, don't create JSON with string operations. Create an object and use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
var expcontent = JSON.stringify({cp: lvupxp, level: ++xp.level});
```