# Why is ++i more efficient than i++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

According to the [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Preincrement_and_Predecrement#Preincrement_and_Predecrement), "when the return value is ignored, the 'pre' form (`++i`) is never less efficient than the 'post' form (`i++`), and is often more efficient."

The guide goes on to explain why, but I don't exactly understand. Thoughts? Perhaps someone could provide an example of this concept?

Comment: With built-in types, they're the same.  With a custom type, prefix is naturally less complicated.

Comment: It isn't necessarily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Comment: ++i increments the value of 'i' immediately therefore in one clock cycle the value is incremented to something new. Whereas i++ takes 2 clock cycles. As far as efficiency goes, that is debatable considering the speed of a clock cycle.

Comment: @maditya that question is for C, not C++. The answers differ.

Comment: Yup, just noticed that after posting, sorry about that. Would it be confusing if I delete the comment?

Comment: I am messing a little now, but since operator overloading, you can never say which one (of *crements) would be faster (at least in C++)

Comment: Removed C tag, as this question, as-asked, has nothing to do with C.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`i++` increments `i` and returns the initial value of `i`. Which means:

```c
int i = 1;
i++; // == 1 but i == 2
```

But `++i` returns the actual incremented value:

```
int i = 1;
++i; // == 2 and i == 2 too, so no need for a temporary variable
```

In the first case, the compiler has to create a temporary variable (when used) for returning `1` instead of `2` (in the case where it's not a constant of course but a dynamic value, a return from a call for example).

In the second case, it does not have to. So the second case is guaranteed to be at least as effective.

Often, the compiler will be able to optimize the first case into the second case, but sometimes it may not be able to.

Anyway, we're talking about highly negligible impact.

But on more complicated objects such as `iterators`-like objects, having a temporary state may be pretty slower if iterated millions of times.

**Rule of thumb**

Use prefix version unless you specifically want the postfix semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/increment-pre-post-speed.html

++i is sometimes faster than, and is never slower than, i++.

For intrinsic types like int, it doesn't matter: ++i and i++ are the same speed. For  class types like iterators, ++i very well might be faster than i++ since the latter might make a copy of the this object.

The overhead of i++, if it is there at all, won't probably make any practical difference unless your app is CPU bound. For example, if your app spends most of its time waiting for someone to click a mouse, doing disk I/O, network I/O, or database queries, then it won't hurt your performance to waste a few CPU cycles. However it's just as easy to type ++i as i++, so why not use the former unless you actually need the old value of i.

So if you're writing i++ as a statement rather than as part of a larger expression, why not just write ++i instead? You never lose anything, and you sometimes gain something. Old line C programmers are used to writing i++ instead of ++i. E.g., they'll say,

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) ....
```

Since this uses i++ as a statement, not as a part of a larger expression, then you might want to use ++i instead. For symmetry, I personally advocate that style even when it doesn't improve speed, e.g., for intrinsic types and for class types with postfix operators that return void.

Answer (score 0):

i++ - the value is incremented after i is used
++i - the value is immediately incremented.

There may be a performance difference because ++i asks that i be immediately incremented, period. i++ goes on to suggest that i may be need before it is incremented. That value may be stored somewhere before being incremented.

Answer (score 0):

The increment (or decrement) operator involves two operations: increment and take one of the two values (old or new) as a result of the expression. The difference is which one to take.

If you take the pre-form, you first increment and then take the value, the new one.

Of you tale the post-form, you take the old value, keep it, increment it, put the new one into the old position and return the old one. This sounds more complicated - and it is.

But if the return value of the expression is ignored,it should make no difference at all, no matter if you have a built-in type or an object.

Answer (score 0):

For iterators and other template types, use pre-increment.

Comment: The question was about "why is that this way".

Comment: This is because post-increment (or decrement) requires a copy of i to be made, which is the value of the expression. If i is an iterator or other non-scalar type, copying i could be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you postincrement, you have to:

1. Change the value and at the same time
2. assign the old value to something else.

Simply you have to keep two copies of that variable, and the copying and deleting is what takes the extra time...