# C++ Printing a string in reverse using a for loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, reverse

I have a program that prints out the characters of a string using a for-loop. It must also print the same characters in reverse, which is where I'm having problems. Can someone help me figure out why the second for-loop isn't executing?

```
int main()
{
    string myAnimal;

    cout << "Please enter the name of your favorite animal.\n";
    cin >> myAnimal;

    // This loop works fine
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < myAnimal.length(); i++){
        cout << myAnimal.at(i) << endl;
    }

    // This one isn't executing
    for(i = myAnimal.length(); i > -1; i--){
        cout << myAnimal.at(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not use int to store the length of the string the length of the string may exceed the integer range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign i initially to the length minus one, or the last index value in the array.

```
for(i = myAnimal.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
    cout << myAnimal.at(i) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Addendum: this is what the runtime error message "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'", or similar, that you should have gotten, was trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the character positions start at 0, the last character of `myAnimal` is at position `(myAnimal.length()-1)` not `myAnimal.length()` so you want to start the second loop there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [reverse iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string myAnimal;

  std::cout << "Please enter the name of your favorite animal.\n";
  std::cin >> myAnimal;

  // Iterate in reverse order
  for(auto c = myAnimal.rbegin(); c != myAnimal.rend(); ++c) {
    std::cout << *c << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Note that you have to increment the variable 'c' (and not decrement it) since this is a reverse iterator.

Answer (score 0):

@Lokno already provided you with the correct answer. However, let me nitpick your code a bit more to show you some other alternatives and to correct some minor mistakes.

First, you didn't actually post a compiling example, because you forgot to show the included headers `<iostream>` and `<string>` and also didn't show the `using namespace std;` that was implicit in your code.

Second, for the regular `for` loop, prefer to keep the loop variable inside the loop, unless you actually need to use it as a return value. Also [**prefer pre-increment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c?lq=1) `++i` over post-increment `i++`. Furthermore, because you have made sure of the correct loop indices, there is no reason to use the bounds-checked element access `at()` over the unchecked `[]` version.

In C++11, you have the range-for loop which allows for even shorter and more fool-proof code, where I also used `auto` where you could have used `char`. Unfortunately, there is no reverse range-for loop. The correct index-based reverse for loop is probably easier to read if you use `i >= 0` rather than `i > -1`.

Then there is an algorithm based loop using `std::copy` where you use the iterator interface of `std::string` (in particular the reverse iterators `rbegin()` and `rend()`) to copy each character through an `ostream_iterator` that is bound to standard output.

BTW, I used the separator `"|"` rather than the newline to see stuff more easier, adapt to your taste. In any case, using `std::endl` can have [**performance implications**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) because it flushes the output buffer every time.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream> // you forgot this
#include <string>   // you forgot this

int main()
{
    using namespace std;    // you forgot this

    // let's pretend this is the string
    string myAnimal = "Please enter the name of your favorite animal.";

    // keep the loop variable local, prefer pre-increment
    for (int i = 0; i < myAnimal.length(); ++i)
        cout << myAnimal[i] << "|";    // prefer [] over at()
    std::cout << "\n";

    // C++11 range-for
    for (auto c : myAnimal)
        std::cout << c << "|";
    std::cout << "\n";

    // index-based reverse loop
    for (int i = myAnimal.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        cout << myAnimal[i] << "|";
    std::cout << "\n";

    // algorithm-based reverse loop
    std::copy(myAnimal.rbegin(), myAnimal.rend(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, "|"));
    std::cout << "\n";

    // main implicitly return 0
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90e403b9a6b91754). PS: `main()` implicitly returns `0` upon success.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(myAnimal.length(); i > -1; i--){
    ^
```

this doesn't do anything. you fetch the value and then throw it away.

Did you mean `i = myAnimal.length() - 1` ?

Comment: Sorry, did a quick edit. Should have been i = myAnimal.length().

Answer (score -3):

Instead of

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < myAnimal.length(); i++){
    cout << myAnimal.at(i) << endl;
}

// This one isn't executing
for(i = myAnimal.length(); i > -1; i--){
    cout << myAnimal.at(i) << endl;
}
```

write

```
for ( string::size_type i = 0; i < myAnimal.length(); i++ ){
    cout << myAnimal.at(i) << endl;
}

// This one isn't executing
for ( string::size_type i = myAnimal.length(); i != 0; ){
    cout << myAnimal.at( --i) << endl;
}
```

In your code you try to access an element of the string that is beyond the acceptable range that is equal to [0, length() - 1]

Also instead of type int it is better to use the type that std::string provides for the return type of member function length that is std::string::size_type.

Comment: You should at least *try* to explain why your change helps.  Also, moving the loop increment into the `cout` operation is clever, but generally considered bad style.