# Is there a Fortran equivalent of Python's for-else statement?

Tags: python, fortran, for-else

Is there a Fortran equivalent of Python's for-else statement?

For example, the following sorts a list of numbers into different ranges.  In Python, it is:

```
absth = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
vals = [.1, .2, .5, 1.2, 3.5, 3.7, 16.8, 19.8, 135.60]


counts = [0] * len(absth)
for v in vals:
    for i, a in enumerate(absth):
        if v < a:
            counts[i] += 1
            break
    else:
        counts[-1] += 1
```

In Fortran, this works the same:

```
do iv = 1, nvals

  is_in_last_absth = .true.

  do ia = 1, nabsth - 1
    if vals(iv) < absth(ia) then
      counts(ia) = counts(ia) + 1
      is_in_last_absth = .false.
      exit
    end if
  end do

  if (is_in_last_absth) then
    counts(nabsth) = counts(nabsth) + 1
  end if

end do
```

But is there a way to not have to use `is_in_last_absth` and replace it with something like the `else` in Python?

Comment: Python with NumPy and Fortran are very similar in terms of expressiveness and features. This rosetta stone shows how to implement many common idioms in both languages side by side. http://www.fortran90.org/src/rosetta.html

Comment: This question should be linked with the [equivalent question for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24693694), especially since both Fortran and C++ are compiled, OO languages, so the suggested solutions are similar.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct equivalent to that python construct.

Note though, that early termination of a do loop with a counted loop control can be detected by examining the value of the do variable after the loop.

```
do iv = 1, nvals
  do ia = 1, nabsth - 1
    if (vals(iv) < absth(ia)) then
      counts(ia) = counts(ia) + 1
      exit
    end if
  end do

  ! If the loop terminates because it completes the iteration 
  ! count (and not because the exit statement is executed) then 
  ! the do variable is one step beyond the value it had 
  ! during the last iteration.
  if (ia == nabsth) then
    counts(nabsth) = counts(nabsth) + 1
  end if
end do
```

An exit statement can also jump out of more than just do loops:

```
do iv = 1, nvals
  outer_block: block
    do ia = 1, nabsth - 1
      if (vals(iv) < absth(ia)) then
        counts(ia) = counts(ia) + 1
        exit outer_block
      end if
    end do

    counts(nabsth) = counts(nabsth) + 1
  end block outer_block
end do
```

and a cycle statement can cycle any do construct that the statement is nested within:

```
outer_loop: do iv = 1, nvals
  do ia = 1, nabsth - 1
    if (vals(iv) < absth(ia)) then
      counts(ia) = counts(ia) + 1
      cycle outer_loop
    end if
  end do

  counts(nabsth) = counts(nabsth) + 1
end do outer_loop
```

Answer (score 3):

If the question is specifically about binning a series of numbers, with `absth` being the upper limits on each bin (bar the last which has no upper limit), then I'd probably write something like this:

```
PROGRAM test

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER :: ix   
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(5) :: absth = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   
  REAL, DIMENSION(9) :: vals = [.1, .2, .5, 1.2, 3.5, 3.7, 16.8, 19.8, 135.60]   
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(SIZE(absth)+1) :: bins

  bins = 0

  DO ix = 1, SIZE(bins)-1
     bins(ix) = COUNT(vals<absth(ix))   
  END DO   
  bins(ix) = COUNT(vals)

  bins = bins-EOSHIFT(bins,-1)
  WRITE(*,*) 'bins = ', bins
  ! which writes  3  1  0  2  0  3

END PROGRAM test
```

then, when I was happy that the logic was correct I'd turn it into a function and add in some error checking.

If the question is more general, and asks what is the idiomatic Fortran (post 90) way to reproduce Python's `for-else` structure, there are answers here to that too.

Answer (score 2):

GO TO statements allow arbitrary jumps.  In particular, you write your for loop followed by the else block, followed by a labeled continue.  Within the loop, if the condition is true then jump to the labeled continue.  Otherwise the for loop will terminate normally, the else block will be executed and then the continue, exactly matching the semantics of python's for...else construct.

For example:

```
        INTEGER nabsth, nvals
        PARAMETER (nabsth=5, nvals=9)
        INTEGER absth(nabsth), counts(nabsth)
        REAL vals(nvals)
        DATA absth/1, 2, 3, 4, 5/
        DATA counts/0, 0, 0, 0, 0/
        DATA vals/.1, .2, .5, 1.2, 3.5, 3.7, 16.8, 19.8, 135.60/

        do iv = 1, nvals

          do ia = 1, nabsth - 1
            if (vals(iv) < absth(ia)) then
              counts(ia) = counts(ia) + 1
              goto 10
            end if
          end do
          counts(nabsth) = counts(nabsth) + 1
10        continue
        end do
        WRITE (*,*), counts
        end
```

Produces

```
       3           1           0           2           3
```

Comment: Sometimes a GOTO is worthwhile. There is a difference between using them in placeEXIT and CYCLE. But occasional use is not the greatest sin in the wold

Comment: And if you dust off your VAX emulator you will be able to run it without changing a thing!

Answer (score 2):

Since the `else` part of Python's for-else block is executed only when all the elements are processed, how about simply using the `if` statement for the last element? For example,

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer i, n
    print *, "n = ?" ; read(*,*) n

    do i = 1, 10
        if ( i <= n ) then
            print *, i
        else
            exit
        endif
        if ( i == 10 ) print *, "reached the final index"
    enddo

    print *, "done"
end program
```

which probably corresponds to

```
n = int( input( "n = ? \n" ) )

for i in range( 1, 11 ):
    if i <= n:
        print( i )
    else:
        break
else:
    print( "reached the final index" )

print( "done" )
```

Another way might be to use a labeled `block` construct, for example:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer i, n
    print *, "n = ?" ; read(*,*) n

    loop_i : block

      do i = 1, 10
          if ( i <= n ) then
              print *, i
          else
              exit loop_i
          endif
      enddo
      print *, "reached the final index"

    endblock loop_i

    print *, "done"
end program
```

According to Chap.20.1.7: "Exit from nearly any construct" in *Modern Fortran Explained* (by Metcalf et al) and also the F2008 Standards [Chap.8.1.10](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) (obtained from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran/info)), it is OK to exit from any labeled construct like `block`, `if`, `associate` etc, but we may need a relatively new compiler (gfortran-6 worked for me). The IBM man page for [exit](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2MB5_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/exit.html) is also useful.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have confirmed the documents. Though I have never used "do concurrent" nor "critical" up to now, I will check the usage later :)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Python is the only (or one of the very few) languages that has a for-else statement. No, Fortran does not have it.

Comment: So how does a WHERE ELSEWHERE differ from python's "for else"?

Comment: Python's `else` is executed *after* the loop if the loop did not break. `elsewhere`, as far as I can tell, is executed in the loop at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes GOTO is good.
A WHERE ELSEWHERE may be useful...

```
do iv = 1, nvals

  is_in_last_absth = .true.
  Mask = .FALSE.
  Mask(1:(nabsth - 1)) = .TRUE.)
  Mask2 = .FALSE.
  WHERE(MASK)
    WHERE( vals(iv) < absth)
      mask2 = .TRUE.
    ENDWHERE

    WHERE(Mask2)
      Count = Count + 1
    ELSE
      LastCount = LastCount + 1
    ENDWHERE

  END WHERE
end do

count(2:(n-1)) = count(2:(n-1))+ lastcount(1:(n))
```