# Difference between i++ and ++i?

Tags: c, short-circuiting

This is My Code:

```
int main()
{
    int i=2,j=2,c=2,d;

    d= ++i || ++j && c;
    printf("I is %d\n",i);
    printf("J is %d\n",j);
    printf("C is %d\n",c);
    printf("D is %d\n",d);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the following code is:

```
i is 3                                                                                                                                                                          
j is 2                                                                                                                                                                          
c is 2                                                                                                                                                                          
d is 1
```

Now my question is, if `++i` is `3` then why `++j` is 2?

What is the difference between `++i` & `i++`? Also I want to know that how come `d` is `1` ?

Comment: why is value of J still 2 after ++j?

Comment: note that `++j` is never executed. there must be some question about short-circuiting and logical operators already

Comment: Well, the duplicate everyone is voting for certainly answers the *title* of this question. Too bad the *question* doesn't really match its own title (or the duplicate-selection).

Answer (score 7):

You asked:

> Now my question is if ++i is 3 then why ++j is 2?

`++j` is never executed since `++i` evaluates to true.

The expression `++i || ++j && c` is equivalent to `++i || (++j && c)` due to operator precedence.

The run time evaluates the expression `++i || ++j && c` from left to right.
The first term, `++i` evaluates to `3`, with the side effect that the value of `i` is `3`. Since it is non-zero, the run time does not need to evaluate anything after that. Since `++j` is never evaluated, the value of `j` is not changed.

> What is the difference between `++i` & `i++`?

The value of the expression `++i` is `i+1` with the side effect that the value of `i` is incremented by `1`.

The value of the expression `i++` is `i` with the side effect that the value of `i` is incremented by `1`.

```
int i = 2;
int x = ++i;  // x == 3, i == 3 at the end of execution of the statement
int y = i++;  // y == 3, i == 4 at the end of execution of the statement
```

> I want to know that howcome D is 1

The value of `d` is set to 1 since the boolean value of the expression is `true`.

Answer (score 5):

++i is pre increment.
i++ is post increment.
Suppose here `i = 2`

In Post In crement

```
printf("%d",i++); // it will print output 2 then increment value of i to 3
```

In Pre Increment

```
printf("%d",++i); //first it will increment value of i to 3, then print output 3
```

---

```
d= ++i || ++j && c;
```

Condition will be performed in this manner `++i || (++j && c);`
As i=2, after `++i` it will become `3`.
In **OR** if first condition is true it will skip second condition. means `++j && c` will not be performed.
Result of `++i || ++j && c` is `1`
so d = 1.

---

```
printf("I is %d\n",i);  // i = 3;
printf("J is %d\n",j);  // j = 2;
printf("C is %d\n",c);  // c = 2;
printf("D is %d\n",d);  // d = 1;
```

[Short Circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. So it will first solve `++i`, and then if that is false, solve `++j && c`  , and finally solve those two things `||`'d together.

Comment: @MattMcNabb , If the expression is `++i || (++j && c)`, then isn't `(++j && c)` supposed to be executed first as they are in parenthesis?

Comment: @CoolGuy no, parentheses has nothing to do with order of evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the evaluation is **short-circuiting** of the boolean operators `&&` and `||`.

- For `&&`, if the left-hand side expression is false, the combined result is false (the right-hand side expression is never evaluated).
- For `||`, if the left-hand side expression is true, the combined result is true (the right-hand side expression is **never** evaluated).

This is mostly important when the right-hand expression has **side effects**, such as altering values(or calling some functions with side-effects), for example in your case:

```
d= ++i || ++j && c;
```

Note that the combined conditional expression would increment `i` by `1` since the conditional expression on the left of `||` is true, the conditional expression on the right-hand side i.e. `++j && c` is never evaluated.

Thus, the total expression will lead eventually to:

```
d = 1 || ++j && c;
```

which explains **why d=1?**

Now if you change the value of `i=-1` then the expression on the right of the `||` will be executed and the `j` will be incremented as per your expectation

> Now for the performance effects of i++ vs ++i check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) :)