# Operator precedence in C for the statement z=++x||++y&&++z

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I was studying operator precedence and I am not able to understand how the value of `x` became `2` and that of `y` and `z` is `1`

```
x=y=z=1;

z=++x||++y&&++z;
```

This evaluates to

```
x=2 y=1 z=1
```

Comment: Undefined behavior, on operator `z`.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998697/difference-between-i-and-i);

Comment: @rakeb.void Not in this case. `||` (and `&&`) is a sequence point, and its short-circuiting behavior avoids evaluation of `++z`.

Comment: Why write code that is difficult to read? Job security problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "++x || ++y && ++z" calculate "++x" first, even though operator "&&" has higher precedence than "||"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700352/why-does-x-y-z-calculate-x-first-even-though-operator-ha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++` has higher priority than `||`, so the whole RHS of the assignment boils down to an increment of `x` and an evaluation to a truth value (1).

```
z = ++x         ||  ++y&&++z;
    truthy (1)     never executed
```

This is because `++x` evaluates to true and the second branch is not executed. `++x` is `2` which, in a boolean context, evaluates to true or `1`. `z` takes the value of `1`, giving you the observed final state.

Comment: One of `z = ++x||0;` or `z = !!++x;` or `z = (_Bool)++x;` or `z = ++x ? 1 : 0;` would be more appropriate. `z = ++x;` would be `z = 2;`

Answer (score 5):

```
x=y=z=1
z=++x||++y&&++z
```

is equivalent to

```
x=y=z=1
z=((++x)||((++y)&&(++z)));
```

Since `++x` returns `2`, which is nonzero, the `++y && ++z` branch is never executed, and thus the code is equivalent to:

```
x=y=z=1;
z=(++x)||(anything here);
```

Answer (score 4):

`z=++x||++y&&++z;`

NOTE: `++` has higher priority than `||`

Now after this line is executed the value of `x` is incremented and `x=2` now `++y&&++z` are never executed as the first condition is true and hence you are getting the value as `x=2 y=1 z=1`

Answer (score 3):

The *and* `&&` and the *or* `||` operation is executed from left to right and moreover, in C `0` means `false` and any non-zero value means `true`. You write

```
x=y=z=1;
z= ++x || ++y && ++z;
```

As, `x = 1`, so the statement `++x` is `true`. Hence the further condition `++y && ++z` not executed.

So the output became:

```
x=2 // x incremented by 1
y=1 // as it is
z=1 // assigned to true (default true = 1)
```

Now try this,

```
z= ++y && ++z || ++x ;
```

You will get

```
x=1 // as it is because ++y && ++z are both true 
y=2 // y incremented by 1
z=1 // although z incremented by 1 but assigned to true (default true = 1)
```

And finally try this:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 0;
int z = 1;

z= y && ++z || ++x;
```

The output will be:

So the output became:

```
x=2 
y=0 
z=0
```

Because, now the statement for z is look like this:

```
z = false (as y =0) && not executed || true
z = false || true
z = true
```

So, `y` remains same, x incremented and became `2` and finally `z` assigned to `true`.