# explanation on javascript variables inside a function

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and came across a topic which mentions that the variables declared inside a function is available anywhere inside the function and javascript puts the variable definition at the top like in the below example:

```
var functionScope=function(){
for (var i=0; i< 10; i++){//code inside this loop}
return i;
}
console.log(functionScope()); //prints 10
```

The javascript actually turns the above function to the below:

```
var functionScope=function(){
  var i;
  for ( i=0; i< 10; i++){//code inside the for loop}
  return i;
  }
console.log(functionScope()); //prints 10
```

Since javascript is interpreted language, it executes line by line. How will it know that it should pull the variable to the top of the function after it has tried accessing the variable. When it tries to access the variable it should tell as `undefined` right?

Also if I go by the theory that the variables will be placed at the top of the function and can be accessed anywhere then the below code should print `10`, but why the below code prints `undefined`?

```
var functionScope=function(){
  console.log('The value os i is '+i);
  var i = 20;
}
console.log(functionScope());
```

Could someone explain where my understanding is wrong?

One more doubt: Typically in Java, if I had to print the value of i outside the for loop, i would get an error, but in javascript does the variable still accessible outside outside the for loop  as in case of fist example where the variable is defined inline inside the for loop. Am i missing something here?

Comment: The *variable* itself is hoisted. Its *value* isn't. Prior to the assignment, `i` exists but is `undefined`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: As @FrédéricHamidi has pointed out, there is a difference between the varialbe being available (the var declaration hoisted) and it having a value other then `undefined`. It's the declaration thats hoisted not the asignment.

Comment: `for (i=0; i< 10; i++);` seriously? Look at that `;`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : so you mean that in my third example also, the variable will be hoisted?

Comment: Yes. Variables always are.

Comment: One more doubt added to my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `var`, you tell the JS that the variable is not global, and it'll be aviable only inside the function.

With `=`, you can set the variable's value.

`var i; for (i = 0; ...` and `for (var i = 0; ...` is the same.

In the third example, you don't have `i` inside the function. In this case, the JS'll try to find it as a global variable, outside the function. If you've set `window.i = 1`, it'll print `The value os i is 1`, otherwise it'll generate an error, because `i` is not defined nowhere.

```
var i = 0;
var fn = function() {
    i = 1; //window.i = 1;
};
console.log(i); //prints 1


var i = 0;
var fn = function() {
    var i = 1; //fn.i = 1;
}
console.log(i); //prints 0


var fn = function() {
    var i = 1; //fn.i = 1;
}
console.log(i); //ReferenceError: i is not defined

var i;
var fn = function() {
    var i = 1; //fn.i = 1;
}
console.log(i) //prints undefined
```

As Sebastien C. has already told you, your example code dosn't do what you want it to do. `for (var i=0; i< 10; i++);` means `for (var i=0; i< 10; i++) {/*do nothing*/}`. If you remove the `;`, you'll notece your function will return `0`, because the `return` keyword stops the function, and it return the value, no other operations will be executed, your loop will run only once.

Also, you should use [++i](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39306/2625561).

Answer (score 2):

```
var functionScope=function(){
for (var i=0; i< 10; i++);
    return i
}
console.log(functionScope()); //prints 10
```

This is only a bad indentation. Because of the `;` at the end of `for`, it doesn't includes the `return i` statement into the loop.

There is the well indented one to help you understand what really happens:

```
var functionScope=function() {
    for (var i=0; i< 10; i++) 
        /* do nothing */;
    return i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Javascript is interpreted and whenever is finds a var declared/undeclared, it declares it and then performs the operations or in technical terms it does [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). So now the variable is declared, but is `undefined`.

So any operation done on it (other than assignment) will result in its value being `undefined` only. eg;

```
{
    x++ ; 
    var x = 10 ;
    console.log(x);
}
```

will print `10`. So you can think of it as

```
{
    var x = undefined; \\variable hoisted at beginning of block 
    x++ ; 
    x = 10 ;
    console.log( x ); \\ x = 10
}
```