# Why is javac creating an unused variable with the postfix "++" operator on a class?

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) I started out on a little research.

I was able to determine that using primitives, the prefix `++i` just gets rewritten to `i++` by the compiler:

Before:

```
public class PrefixIncrement {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }   
    }
}
```

Decompiled with jd-gui 0.36:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class PrefixIncrement
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Okay.  So that part was answered.  But then I stumbled across what happens when we use the Integer class instead, this time with Postfix:

Before:

```
public class PostfixIncrement {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for( Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

After decompilation:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class PostfixIncrement
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Integer localInteger1;
    Integer localInteger2;
    for (Integer i = Integer.valueOf(0); i.intValue() < 100; localInteger2 = i = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1))
    {
      System.out.println(i);localInteger1 = i;
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler seems to do some stupid stuff with “i++.”  It creates two new integer classes and creates a logically unnecessary series of assignments:

`localInteger2 = i = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1);`

`localInteger1` doesn’t appear to ever be used.  Its just allocated on the stack.  Why is javac doing this?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

===================BY REQUEST:  javap output=======================

Postfix Increment using the `Integer` class.

```
{
  public com.foo.PostfixIncrement();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>
":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       5     0  this   Lcom/matt/PostfixIncrement;

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=4, args_size=1
         0: iconst_0
         1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueO
f:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
         4: astore_1
         5: aload_1
         6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intVal
ue:()I
         9: bipush        100
        11: if_icmpge     40
        14: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljav
a/io/PrintStream;
        17: aload_1
        18: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.prin
tln:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        21: aload_1
        22: astore_2
        23: aload_1
        24: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intVal
ue:()I
        27: iconst_1
        28: iadd
        29: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueO
f:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        32: dup
        33: astore_1
        34: astore_3
        35: aload_2
        36: pop
        37: goto          5
        40: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 5: 0
        line 6: 14
        line 5: 21
        line 8: 40
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               5      35     1     i   Ljava/lang/Integer;
               0      41     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
           frame_type = 252 /* append */
             offset_delta = 5
        locals = [ class java/lang/Integer ]
           frame_type = 250 /* chop */
          offset_delta = 34

}
```

Comment: What was the original code with the `Integer` class? That's the one that matters and you don't show here. Did you look at the generated bytecode? Decompilation is not necessarily an accurate representation of the actual source code.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel -->  I updated with the "Integer" version.  The short version is just to replace "int" with "Integer" in the for loop declaration.

Comment: Don't rely on autoboxing for arithmetic operations. Use built-in types instead (`int`). Relying on autoboxing will lead to hidden performance issues like the one you're seeing.

Comment: You should also post the `javap` output. Sometimes decompilers insert crazy local variables that are not really there when they encounter stack operations like `DUP`, whose semantics are not expressible in Java.

Comment: You rely on the decompiler output to deduce that for the int case ++i is becoming i++; thats *not* whats *really* happening - when javac compiles either, it will emit multiple byte codes; some related to handling the value of the expression and a separate (iinc) to do the actual increment. Its the order of byte codes that determines if its a pre- or post-increment. Since the value was not used, the compiler omitted the value handling byte codes, reducing both cases to a simple iinc. The semantic information if it has been a pre- or postincrement is thus no longer present in byte code

Comment: @Clashsoft I added javap output for the Postfix using an `Integer` class.

Comment: @rustyx -- Currently, the code under question isn't using autoboxing, its a direct instance of the `Integer` class.  see `for( Integer i = 0; ...`

Comment: Of course it does use autoboxing. `Integer` is an immutable object. I'm impossible to 'iterate' it. Attempting `++` will unbox it, increment a built-in type, then autobox the result back.

Comment: @rustyx I did some research and stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the `javap` output of your class (compiled with `javac` 1.8.0_60), the variables do not actually exist:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
     0: iconst_0
     1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
     4: astore_1
     5: aload_1
     6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
     9: bipush        100
    11: if_icmpge     34
    14: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    17: aload_1
    18: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    21: aload_1
    22: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
    25: iconst_1
    26: iadd
    27: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    30: astore_1
    31: goto          5
    34: return
```

(Local variables are used with `*LOAD` and `*STORE` instructions, and as you can see, there is only a single one involved.)

The problem seems to be caused by decompiler, which probably doesn't support boxing within `for` statements really well. So `javac` does nothing wrong, it's just the decompiler's fault. No need to worry about performance impacts or anything, unless you plan on reverse-engineering and saving the decompiled code :P.

Comment: I posted the javap output from the javac version that I'm using.  It appears that it must be related to the `DUP` and `STORE` issue as you suggest.

Comment: It seems like the Java 7 compiler does things a bit differently. I recommend upgrading to Java 8 anyway, since 7 is not supported anymore.

Comment: Remember that it's possible for an application to require rewriting from JDK version to JDK version.  Politics can keep that from being priority.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of the int version of prefix ++ is:  `++i` is simpler: `i = i + 1; return i`.

Whereas `i++` means a more complicated thing: `int i$ = i; i = i + 1; return i$`.

When int is wrapped in an Integer the used compiler evidently does not generate sufficiently intelligent code. It actually maintains the old value of `i` (`i$` above). No reason to be that dumb, as the result of `i++` is not used at that position.

```
for (...; ...; (void)[[ i++ ]] ) {
```

generates in the first instance

```
Integer i$ = i;
i = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1);
"return" i$ to a void context
drop variable i$ where i$ is unused
```

Which should easily have been reduced to:

```
i = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1);
```

Comment: Actually, I doubt the compiler needs a synthetic local variable to do that operation; a `DUP` should also do the job. And that in turn works just as well with a boxed integer.

Comment: @Clashsoft local variable and expression stack are just slightly different alternatives. A `DUP`  of the Integer object of `i` can be done as Integer is **immutable**. And that duplication would be unneeded too after usage analysis.

Comment: I doubt a reasonably smart compiler would know that it doesn't even need one in the context of a `for` statement's update code, since it's expected type is `void` anyway. I just wanted to point out that saying "*`i++` means a more complicated thing: `int i$ = i; i = i + 1; return i$`*" is not technically correct in all cases. It's just that you can't express `DUP` semantics in *Java* code.

Comment: @Clashsoft `i++` as `dup i; i = i + 1; (pop)` is nicer style indeed. And yes compiler theory can do expression trees resulting in dup and other instructions. Though doubt on intelligence I have too, seeing the complexity of the language constructs.

Comment: On an interesting side-note: When using `i++` (`Integer i`) in an expression context, it either prefers `Object` over unboxing (for `sysout`) or does the `DUP` on the reference rather than the unboxed value, thus inserting two `.intValue()` calls

Answer (score 0):

I suspect those two temporary variables, `localInteger1` and `localInteger2` are placeholders introduced to handle general boxing/unboxing rules. Without looking at the decompiled byte code, which may reveal some details not in the reinterpreted-from-compiled java code, and without looking at some other less trivial cases, I am only speculating.

However, it is obvious though that they are retaining the value of `i` both before and after the loop `ForUpdate` expression.

Consider this case:

```
Integer i;
for( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
System.out.println(i); // what is the value of `i` here?
```

Which is identical in Java code to the case of the primitive other than the declared type being `Integer` instead of `int`.

The compiler must track the value of `i` through and after the execution of the loop, at which point it will be `100`. I suspect there are some cases in implementing a loop and handling the primitive `int` can be done trivially but handling object reference updates includes more complex cases and thus requires the two temporary values.