# PHP - Copy a multidimensional array by grouping its keys based on the values index

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array which looks like this. This is my snippet down below:

```
$tyreSpec = array(
    'width_id' => array(
        0 => '8',
        1 => '24'
    ),
    'profile_id' => array(
        0 => '8',
        1 => '13'
    ),
    'diameter_id' => array(
        0 => '4',
        1 => '13'
    ),
    'speed_id' => array(
        0 => '6',
        1 => '13'
    ),
    'load_id' => array(
        0 => '12',
        1 => '31'
    )
);
```

How can I create an array like this from the above one?

```
$toDb = array (
    array(
          'width_id' => 8,
          'profile_id' => 8,
          'diameter_id' => 4,           
          'speed_id' => 6,
          'load_id' => 12
    ),
    array(
          'width_id' => 24,
          'profile_id' => 13,
          'diameter_id' => 13,           
          'speed_id' => 13,
          'load_id' => 31
    )
);
```

This is my code down below I can't get it done:

```
$ToDb = array();
//$i = 0;
$count = 0;
foreach($tyreSpec as $row ) {
    $count = count($row);
}

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    foreach($tyreSpec as $row) {
        array_push($ToDb, $row[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a key for each array. What you asking is imposible. How you are making the array?

Comment: if you want it dynamically its impossible. Either you have change your array structure or you have to do it statically.

Comment: the array is coming from a post request

Comment: change the array structure. so you mean get rid of the string keys and
convert the associative array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two simple loops to achieve your goal:

```
$toDb = array();
foreach ($tyreSpec as $key=>$val) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($val); ++$i)
        $toDb[$i][$key] = $val[$i];
}
```

Comment: i have a question why you are using ++$i not $i++ ?

Comment: @Share `C` memories... in `C` it saves the space of a temporary variable: for the "math" in a loop `++i` or `i++` is exactly the same

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :) have a great day

Comment: @Share see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39306/1575188) for a reference about what I meant in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
// $source is your input array
$result = [];$result = [];
array_walk($source, function($v,$k) use (&$result){
    $result[0][$k] = $v[0];
    $result[1][$k] = $v[1];
});

print_r($result);
```

Demo is [Here](https://3v4l.org/9H9V0)

Comment: It works perfectly. i will play with this code thank anyway for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
    $initArray = 
    array (
      'width_id' => 
        array (
          0 => string '8',
          1 => string '24'
        ),
      'profile_id' => 
        array (
          0 => string '8',
          1 => string '13'
        ),
      'diameter_id' => 
        array (
          0 => string '4',
          1 => string '13'
        ), 
      'speed_id' => 
        array (
          0 => string '6',
          1 => string '13' 
       ),
      'load_id' => 
        array (
          0 => string '12', 
          1 => string '31'
        )
    )

$newArray = Array();

foreach ($innitArray as $key => $value){
   $newArray[$key][0] = $innitArray[$key][$vallue][0];
   $newArray[$key][1] = $innitArray[$key][$vallue][1];
}
```