# What is the difference between int++ and ++int?

Tags: int, addition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between ++i and i++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)
>   [pre Decrement vs. post Decrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531870/pre-decrement-vs-post-decrement)

Yes I'm a noob, but I completely forgot what they both do.

I know, however, that int++ just adds one to the value of int.

So, what is ++int?

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language you are talking about.

Answer (score 27):

If you're talking about C (or C-like languages), it's exactly the same unless you *use* the value:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a++;
```

In that case, `a` becomes 11 and `b` is set to 10. That's post-increment - you increment *after* use.

If you change that line above to:

```
int b = ++a;
```

then `a` still becomes 11 but so does `b`. That's because it's pre-increment - you increment *before* use.

Note that it's not quite the same thing for C++ classes, there are efficiencies that can be had by preferring one over the other. But since you're talking about integers, C++ acts the same as C.

Comment: That makes sense, meaning "pre" and "post" increment.

Answer (score 5):

a++ will return a and increment it, ++a will increment a and return it:

`a = 5;
b = a++; // b = 5, a = 6`

`a = 5;
b = ++a; // b = 6, a = 6`

Answer (score 3):

Every expression in C or C++ has a type, a value, and possible side-effects.

```
int i;
++i;
```

The type of `++i` is `int`. The side-effect is to increment `i`. The value of the expression is the **new** value of `i`.

```
int i;
i++;
```

The type of `i++` is `int`. The side-effect is to increment `i`. The value of the expression is the **old** value of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

it's the preincrement operator

[nice explanation here](http://www.sanity-free.com/145/preincrement_vs_postincrement_operators.html)