# What is ++int in Java?

Tags: java, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [explain working of post and pre increment operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/explain-working-of-post-and-pre-increment-operator-in-java)
>   [What is the difference between int++ and ++int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917564/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-int)

In Java, what is `++int`? What does it do? What does it mean?

(Sorry, but I didn't ask the question correctly last time.)

Comment: It's exactly the same as the C++ answer you got in your other question..

Comment: In future, please search before posting a question.

Comment: @Brendan, mostly true, but any differences are fully [elaborated here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6457294/189950).

Answer (score 6):

```
a = 5; b = ++a; // a = 6, b = 6
a = 5; b = a++; // a = 6, b = 5
```

Comment: Other way around: `a` is incremented after the assigment. `b` uses the old value of `a`

Answer (score 2):

```
int a=1;
System.out.println(a++);
```

prints "1"

```
int a=1;
System.out.println(++a);
```

prints "2"

Or maybe i don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

`++int` increments int by 1 before and `int++` increments by one after