# i++ returns i instead of i++

Tags: java, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pre Decrement vs. post Decrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531870/pre-decrement-vs-post-decrement)
>   [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

I've just realized that

```
int i=0;
System.out.println(i++);
```

prints **0** instead of **1**.
I thought that *i* was incremented and THEN printed. It seems that the contrary happens.

Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are the [pre- and post-increment operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators). This behavior is exactly correct.

- `i++` returns the original value.
- `++i` returns the new value.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `i++` the incrementation doesn't happen until the next instruction. It's called a post increment.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(i++);
```

It should first print value of i then increment the i. Its post order increment.

- i++ -> post order increment
- ++i -> pre order increment

Answer (score 2):

```
++i will print 1
i++ will print 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`i++` means return i, then increment. Hence ++ after i.

`++i` means increment i, then return. Hence ++ in front of i

Answer (score 1):

- `i++` => evaluation then increment;
- `++i` => increment then evaluation.

Think about a `for` loop - `i` is incremented after every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The `++` after the variable defines a post-increment operation. This means that after you are done executing everything else on the line, then `i` is increased. If you used `++i` the variable would be incremented before it is printed

Answer (score 1):

As you can find here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html there are two incrementing operators: i++ and ++i. ++i does what you thought i++ would do. i++ increments the value after usage for other purposes (look into the link for more details)

Answer (score 1):

Because the value given to the `System.out.println(i++);`is assigned 0 first then it is incremented.
if you will attempt to do `System.out.println(++i);` then it will display 1 to you.