# for(int i=0;i<myVector.size();++i) How many times is size() called?

Tags: c++, stl

If i have a `myVector` which is a STL vector and execute a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<myVector.size();++i) { ... }
```

Does the C++ compiler play some trick to call `size()` only once, or it will be called `size()+1` times?

I am little confused, can anyone help?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that it will be called size() + 1 times.

Comment: I once [ran some tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926930/it-or-it-when-iterating-over-a-map/6927125#6927125) on a `map` which suggested that the compiler can figure out when to hoist the end out of the loop.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Those are simple tests and not representative of real code. If anywhere in the loop you call out to another non-inlined function, the compiler will almost always have to assume that somewhere else could alias the size, and will reload it on each iteration. It will only be hoisted in very, very simple situations (like your tests).

Comment: @Peter: Yeah, that's true... one more reason to hoist manually for non-modifying loops!

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to get your assembly and dig through it (not fun, but conclusive). `g++ -Owhatever -S file.cpp` will do it on Linux (look for `file.s` afterwards) - just keep in mind that the assembly can differ drastically depending on the optimization level.  Though, personally, I just try to dodge this entirely by starting loops at `size - 1` and going down to zero...  Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically, `myVector.size()` will be called each  time the loop is iterated - or at least the compiler must produce code *as if* it's called each time.

If the optimizer can determine that the size of the vector will not change in the body of the loop, it could hoist the call to `size()` outside the loop. Note that usually, `vector::size()` is an inline that's just a simple difference between pointers to the end and beginning of the vector (or something similar - maybe a simple load of a member that keeps track of the number of elements).

So there's actually probably little reason for concern about what happens for `vector::size()`.

Note that `list::size()` could be a different story - the C++03 standard permits it to be linear complexity (though I think this is rare, and the C++0x standard changes `list::size()` requirements to be constant complexity).

Comment: I'd say if compiler can determine that calling `size ()` has no side effects, not only if method doesn't change the body of the loop, or vector. Simply, it will be called N+1 times even if you insert `printf` there.

Comment: I remember having had a horrible experience with list::size()'s linear complexity (Visual Studio 7.1, i think). The for statement becomes of N² complexity and out went my performance !

Comment: Your compiler must also assume that no other thread is changing your vector. If the vector has changed from another thread, the compiler would need to call `size()` again.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the vector doesn't change size in the loop. If it does change size, it's impossible to tell without knowing how it changes size.

On the C++ abstract machine it will be called exactly `size()+1` times. And on a concrete implementation it will have an observable behaviour equivalent to it having been called `size()+1` times (this is called the *as if* rule).

This means that the compiler can choose to call it just once, because the observable behaviour is the same. In fact, by following the *as if*  rule, if the body of the loop is empty, the compiler can even choose to not call it at all and just skip the whole thing altogether. The observable behaviour is the same, because making your code run faster is not considered different observable behaviour.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging difference between abstract and concrete machine.

Answer (score 2):

It will be called `size + 1` times. Changing the size of the `vector` will affect the number of iterations.

Comment: No, it will behave *as if* it were called `size+1` times, which is not the same as actually being called `size+1` times. (assuming the loop doesn't change the size of the vector.)

Comment: @Rob: If it behaves as if it's called `size+1` times what's the point in making the distinction? If the compiler can make the last `size()` calls have zero cost by not actually doing anything then that's great but it can only do that where calling the function has the same behaviour as not calling the function. In this case you may as well consider the function has been "called" because the language requires it to be called and there can be no observable evidence that it hasn't been called.

Comment: I make the distinction because the question makes the distinction. He is trying to understand the difference between `size()` being *actually* called and "some trick" which allows it to not be called. I take "some trick" to mean optimizations allowed by the language.

Comment: @Rob: For the sake of example, how would you tell if a function defined `inline void fn() {}` is called when a statement `fn();` is executed? It *must* be called but you're unlikely to find any difference between object code generate from similar source code with the statement missing. Every time the compiler translates source code to object code it is performing all sorts of tricks every time; the mapping from a high level language such as C++ to what a CPU actually executes should not be expected to be a simple one-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 2):

It may be called once, may be called `size+1` times, or it may never be called at all. Assuming that the vector size doesn't change, your program will behave *as if* it had been called `size+1` times.

There are two optimizations at play here: first, `std::vector::size()` is probably inlined, so it may never be "called" at all in the traditional sense. Second, the compiler may determine that it evaluate `size()` only once, or perhaps never:

For example, this code might never evaluate `std::vector::size()`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i) { ; }
```

Either of these loops might evaluate `std::vector::size()` only once:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i) { std::cout << "Hello, world.\n"; }
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i) { sum += myVector[i]; }
```

While this loop might evaluate `std::vector::size()` many times:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i) { ExternalFunction(&myVector); }
```

In the final analysis, the key questions are:

- Why do you care?, and
- How would you know?

Why do you care how many times `size()` is invoked? Are you trying to make your program go faster?

How would you even know? Since `size()` has no visible side-effects, how would you even know who many times it was called (or otherwise evaluated)?

Answer (score 1):

It will be called size() + 1 times (it may be that the compiler can recognize it as invariant in the loop, but you shouldn't count on it)

Comment: The compiler would also need to be able to recognize that `std::vector<>::size()` has no side effects, a situation which is more likely if the method is inline-able.

Comment: @dmckee: Don't we have `const` for that?

Comment: @delnan `const` insures that the method does not change the state of the object, but does not insure that it does not print, write to disk, send to the network, etc. Or am I bonkers?

Comment: @dmckee: No, you're right. I guess the compilers that do this optimization either really inline it (easy, since the definition for templated code is available anyway) or have a special annotation for "pure" code (GCC has one) and re-use that (doesn't rely on inlining, which isn't always desired).

Answer (score 1):

It will be called until the condition is not falsified (size() could change each time for example). If `size()` remains constant, it's `size() + 1` times.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80153d8(v=vs.80).aspx) page about `for`:

> for ( init-expression ; cond-expression ; loop-expression )
>
> statement
>
> cond-expression
>
> Before execution of each iteration of statement,
> including the first iteration. statement is executed only if
> cond-expression evaluates to true (nonzero). An expression that
> evaluates to an integral type or a class type that has an unambiguous
> conversion to an integral type. Normally used to test for
> loop-termination criteria.

Comment: Not necessarily, just like `a = 0` won't necessarily assign `a`. In both cases, the program will behave *as if* it did, but if the compiler can prove that another operation (which is probably considers more "better" in some regard) and doesn't affect the program's behavior (save undefined behavior etc.), it's free to replace it with that operation. That's an important difference.

Comment: @delnan We are speaking of the sex of angels. The compiler is free to omit 100% of your program if he can see that it wouldn't change its behaviour. If this is so, is it truly important to repeat that every single instruction could be "ignored"?

Answer (score 0):

It will be called size + 1 times, as Ernest have mentioned. However, if you are sure that size is not changing, you can apply an optimisation and make your code look like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0, e = myVector.size (); i < e; ++i)
```

... in which case `size ()` will be called only once.

Comment: There are those who would argue that it is wiser to leave this optimization to the compiler, at least until you *know* that it isn't doing a good enough job.

Comment: @dmckee: in case of `std::vector` it doesn't matter. In case of more complex things, I think it is easier to just write it this way rather than going and checking if every compiler and every new version of used compiler generates the code you expect, if you really rely on it to be called once.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `myVector.size()` will be inlined, so there will be no call at all. Just comparing register value with memory location. Of course I am talking about release build.

In debug build it will be called `size()+1` times.

EDIT: No doubt that there exists such compiler or STL implementation which cannot optimize `myVector.size()`. But the chances to face them are very low.