# What does a++ mean in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the basics of C programming and I'm kind of new to C, I am failing to understand why the output of my program is:

```
1 2
1 1
```

Quite alright, I understand the output from the first `printf()` but I do not seem to get the logic behind the second `printf()`. Why can't it display `1 2` as well?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, a++);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Comment: Which compiler are you using? With GCC v4.6.2, I get `2 1` for the second line! [And also with GCC v4.3.4](http://ideone.com/6dr0H)

Comment: I removed the C++ tag; this smells like C. You shouldn't ever conflate the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a++` is [***post***-incrementing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) `a`. That is, the value of `a` is copied before it is returned and then it is incremented.

As I mentioned in the comments, [I get a different result to you](http://ideone.com/6dr0H), for the reason I explain below.

If you add `printf("%d\n", a);`, after your last call to `printf()` you'll see `2` because `a` has now been incremented.

If you want to see `1 2`, you could [***pre***-increment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) `a` (that is increment it and then use it), but you need to introduce a sequence point for this to be guaranteed to work because the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified by the standard and you want to use `a` twice:

```
printf("%d ", a);
printf("%d\n", ++a);
```

[See it run!](http://ideone.com/cNe8w)

Comment: No, you should use two separate `printf` statements, because the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. You could just as well see `2 2`.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: I was editing my answer a you typed that.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `a++` evaluates to the current value of `a` and as a *side effect* increments `a` by 1.  The expression `++a` evaluates to the current value of `a` + 1 and as a side effect increments `a` by 1.

If you had written

```
a = 1;
printf("%d\n", a++);
```

you would get the output `1`, because you're asking for the *current value* of `a`.  Had you written

```
a = 1;
printf("%d\n", ++a);
```

you would get the output `2`, because you're asking for the value of `a + 1`.

Now, what's important to remember (especially with `++a`) is that the *side effect* of actually updating `a` doesn't have to happen immediately after the expression has been evaluated; it only has to happen before the next *sequence point* (which, in the case of a function call, is after *all* of the arguments have been evaluated).

Per the language definition, an object (such as the variable `a`) may have its value changed by the evaluation of an expression (`a++` or `++a`) **at most once** between sequence points, and the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

The statement

```
printf("%d %d\n", a, a++);
```

violates the second part of that restriction, so the behavior of that statement is *undefined*.  Your output could be any of `1 1`, `1 2`, a suffusion of yellow, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Post Increment, increament after use

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
    {
      in a = 1, b = 2;

      printf("%d %d\n", a, b);    // 1 1
      printf("%d %d\n", a, a++);  // 1 1
      printf("$d", a); // 2
      return 0;

      }
```

Following is pre-increment :

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
    {
      in a = 1, b = 2;

      printf("%d %d\n", a, b);    // 1 1
      printf("%d %d\n", a, ++a);  // Could Be "1 1" OR "1 2"... sequence is undefined here.
      printf("$d", a); // 2
      return 0;

      }
```

Comment: To repeat what was said above: `printf("%d %d\n",a,++a);` is undefined behavior. You'll probably get "1 2" or "2 2", but anything at all could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ++x and x++ increment x the same way. The only difference is that ++x returns a reference to x and x++ returns the previous value as a temporary. The "incremented after it's been used" explanation is incorrect.

Comment: C (which, despite the C++ tag, is what the OP really appears to be using) doesn't have references. `++x` returns an lvalue and `x++` an rvalue, though using the lvalue from `++x` is clearly a terrible idea.

Comment: Whether a temporary is used depends on the CPU ISA. (Yes, that's how it tends to happen these days.)