# | operator , ++ and I operator

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I think I will get     `12`, not `7`.
 `w++`, then `w` will be `4`, which is `100`, and `w++`, `w` will be `8`, `1000`;
so `w++|z++` will be `100|1000 = 1100` will be `12`.

what's wrong with me?

```
int main()
{
    int  w=3, z=7; 
    printf("%d\n", w++|z++);
}
```

Comment: "what's wrong with me?" We don't know.

Comment: You might be ok...but the operator precedence that you are thinking of is not :)

Comment: You should produce a minimal example showing your problem .. remove the `x` and the `i` and `scanf` bits.

Comment: I know thanks. n++ is after a sentence being caculated. so w++|z++, actually is w|z then, w, and z self++. so the result is 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by using `w++|z++`, you're first using the value of `w` and ORing that by the current value of `z`, then incrementing each.  Use `++w|++z` instead, and the numbers will *first* be incremented, then used.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    // prints 10
    printf("%d\n", x++);
    // prints 11
    printf("%d\n", x);

    x = 10;
    // prints 11
    printf("%d\n" ++x);
    // prints 11
    printf("%d\n" x);
}
```

The same can be done with `--x` and `x--`.  For more information, see [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i).

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the *postfix* `++` operator. The value of the variable is used *before* the variable is incremented. Your analysis would be correct for the *prefix* `++` operator, as in `++w|++z`.

Answer (score 2):

Those are *post* increment operators; they take effect *after* the operation, so 3 and 7 are used in the operation.

Comment: Actually, `w` and `z` _are_ already `4` and `7` when `w++|z++` is used, it just happens that `w++` and `z++` evaluate the the old values of `w` and `z`.

Answer (score 1):

`x++` increments `x`, but it evaluates to the old value of `w`.

So `w++|z++` evaluates to `3|7` (which happens to be 7 on your implementation), and increments `w` and `z` as a side effect.

If you wanted the behaviour that you were expecting, you could use the prefix operator `++x`, which increments its `x` and evaluates to the new value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing post-increment (`i++`) which takes the value of `i` first, then only increases it's value.

If you want to achieve what you said in your question, do this: `++w | ++z`

Answer (score 0):

You have probably misunderstood the `post-increment` operator which is very common among the beginners, so don't worry. Over time you'll get it right.

Take a look at the word `post-increment`. There is a `post` word in it which generally signifies `after`. It means that the increment will happen `after` everything else has been executed. This is how I used to remember it.

So, if you take a look at your program now -

```
int main()
{
    int  w=3, z=7; 
    printf("%d\n", w++|z++);
}
```

then it will become clear that after the `printf` function itself has been executed, the increment will happen. So you will get the value of `w` and `z` as `3` and `7`, respectively in the evaluation of the second argument expression of `printf`.

The official C++11 standard, (§5.2.6, final version) says -

> The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand. [Note:the value obtained is a copy of the original value — end note]

So that means the value of the postfix `w++` expression, is the value of the operand itself, that is, the value of the `w`, which is 3 and the value of the second expression `z++` will be 7. These values will then be used in the calculation of `3|7` and after that, the variables will be incremented.