# Sectioned list view only showing last section

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I have a sectioned list view based on [Jeff Sharkey's](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) implementation. The problem is only one section of the list view is showing (the last one).  Here's how I add the sections:

```
SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);

for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); ++i)    // groups is an ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>>
{
    ArrayList<Person> group = groups.get(i);
    adapter.addSection("Section test", new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_cell, group));
}

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: how many sections are there (in real data)?

Comment: Dheeresh, ++i and i++ have the same effect here.  I've logged the `size` of the arrays and they have the correct data.  8 sections with 2-5 rows per section.

Comment: Here's more info if you want it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Comment: " 8 sections with 2-5 rows per section." i was taking about this info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as need first argument different from previous one in addSection

```
for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); ++i)    // groups is an ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>>
{
    ArrayList<Person> group = groups.get(i);
    adapter.addSection("Section test"+i, new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_cell, group));
}
```

as

in code add function is

```
public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {
this.headers.add(section);
this.sections.put(section, adapter);
}
```

where sections is a Map

```
public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();
```

Comment: Doh! You are right.  I wasn't thinking of the section title as the section key so it was overwriting it every time.  Thanks!