# Java's strange behavior while returning from finally block

Tags: java, return, return-value, finally

Try this piece of code. Why does getValueB() return 1 instead of 2? After all, the increment() function is getting called twice.

```
    public class ReturningFromFinally
    {
      public static int getValueA() // This returns 2 as expected
      {
         try     { return 1; }
         finally { return 2; }
      }

      public static int getValueB() // I expect this to return 2, but it returns 1
      {
        try     { return increment(); }
        finally { increment(); }
      }

      static int counter = 0;

      static int increment()
       {
          counter ++;
          return counter;
       }

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          System.out.println(getValueA()); // prints 2 as expected
          System.out.println(getValueB()); // why does it print 1?
      }
}
```

Comment: It would return `2` if you had `finally { return increment(); }`. The first `return` statement's expression is evaluated prior to the finally block. See [Section §14.20.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

Comment: or if he had ++counter, it would return 2 in the second method `getValue2`

Comment: perhaps it would be better to call diferent incrementxxx() funcions (one in the `return`, other in the `finally`) that increments the by different amounts, just to get a better insight of the problem

Comment: @ant no it wouldn't. `counter++;` and `++counter;` are expression statements and have the same effect.

Comment: yp, true story it wouldn't. in this case they have the same effect, not always though http://stackoverflow.com/a/24858/169277

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> After all, the increment() function is getting called twice.

Yes, but the return value is determined *before* the second call.

The value returned is determined by the evaluation of the expression in the return statement *at that point in time* - not "just before execution leaves the method".

From [section 14.17 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17):

> A return statement with an Expression attempts to transfer control to the invoker of the method that contains it; the value of the Expression becomes the value of the method invocation. More precisely, **execution of such a return statement first evaluates the Expression**. If the evaluation of the Expression completes abruptly for some reason, then the return statement completes abruptly for that reason. If evaluation of the Expression completes normally, producing a value V, then the return statement completes abruptly, the reason being a return with value V.

Execution is *then* transferred to the `finally` block, as per [section 14.20.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2). That doesn't re-evaluate the expression in the return statement though.

If your finally block were:

```
finally { return increment(); }
```

then that new return value would be the ultimate result of the method (as per section 14.20.2) - but you're not doing that.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't return anything or throw any exceptions out of a finally block.  If you do, it obscures the previously issued return value (inside the try), or any exception which has been thrown as part of the try/catch logic.

Answer (score 5):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977626/javas-strange-behavior-while-returning-from-finally-block/11977707#comment15967945_11977626).

It would return `2` if you had `finally { return increment(); }`.
The first `return` statement's expression is evaluated prior to the finally block. See [Section §14.20.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

> If execution of the `try` block completes normally, then the `finally` block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
> - If the `finally` block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes normally.
> - **If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason `S`, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `S`.**

Calling `getValue2` (as you have it now) twice would result in `1` followed by `3`.

Answer (score 0):

the `finally` block in `GetValue2` method does not return anything. It's only calling the method to increment `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

Because in you're getValue2() method, you're finally block just calls increment(), it does not return it. So what your code is doing is it increments and returns counter (1), and then increments counter to 2, but doesn't return it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an explicit return in the second example. In this case, it will return the value within the `try` block. It makes intuitive sense because `Java` has already executed the code inside the `try` block. It would not the executed that block again after executing the `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the finally method is to ensure that ressources are closed in any case.
Consider the example:

```
public List<Person> getPersons() {
    Connection conn = openConnection();
    try {
        return selectPersons(conn);
    } finally {
        conn.close()
    }
}
```

The conn.close() statement is executed AFTER selectPersons(conn) is executed.
Otherwise selectPersons(conn) would raise an connection closed error.