# Finally block does not set values of variable in java

Tags: java

I have the below code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            System.out.println("Hardik::"+testFinnalyBlock());  
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("hhh");
        }
    }


    public static int testFinnalyBlock() throws Exception{
        int a=5,b=10;
        int sum=0;
        try{
            sum = a+b;
            System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
            return sum;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In Catch");
        }finally{
            sum = a+30;
            System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
//          return 1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

The output of above code it 
Hardik::15,
While  i think it should be Hardik::35.

Can Anyone tell me how it works.
Thanks.

Comment: remove return sum; from try block

Comment: Actually remove return sum from try and change return 1 to return sum.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977626/javas-strange-behavior-while-returning-from-finally-block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `finally` block is being executed, based on your output...

```
sum===15
sum===35
Hardik::15
```

The problem is, the `return` statement in the `try-catch` section.  `finally` won't update the value begin returned to the caller, because that value has already being placed in another part of memory...

**Update**

I'm a pretty old school, so I believe in one entry point and one exit point for all my methods...

Something like the following would produce the result you're trying to get...

```
public static int testFinnalyBlock() throws Exception {
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    int sum = 0;
    try {
        sum = a + b;
        System.out.println("sum===" + sum);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("In Catch");
    } finally {
        sum = a + 30;
        System.out.println("sum===" + sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you need to return a different value because of the error, you should be modifying `sum` in the `catch` section of your `try-catch`

Answer (score 2):

Remove `return` form try block and add at the end of the method.
Try this code

```
   public static int testFinnalyBlock() throws Exception{
    int a=5,b=10;
    int sum=0;
    try{
        sum = a+b;
        System.out.println("sum==="+sum);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("In Catch");
    }finally{
        sum = a+30;
        System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
    //          return 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

use finally block for clean up activity,not for logic.It is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return sum` from try block and you will get your desired output.
like..

```
try{
   sum = a+b;
   System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
}
catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("In Catch");
}
finally{
   sum = a+30;
   System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
}
return sum;
```

Comment: That is wrong, the exception is not the problem. If he write a return into a black(here try) the program stops and return and is not able to reach the finally block. ^^

Answer (score 0):

remove comment from // return 1; and put return sum; there you get your answer .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
        System.out.println("Hardik::"+testFinnalyBlock());  
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("hhh");
    }
}


public static int testFinnalyBlock() throws Exception{
    int a=5,b=10;
    int sum=0;
    try{
        sum = a+b;
        System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
        return sum;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("In Catch");
    }finally{
        sum = a+30;
        System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
 return sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think if you do it like so, you have the same problem. After the first return the method exits!

Answer (score 0):

you are using return statement under the try block and sum=a+b and print statement does not throw any exception that is why control goes back to main method with the value of sum 15 that is why your Output is  Hardik::15. if you want the output as expected you should remove return statement from try and where you put the line return 1, replace it with return sum
like :

```
 public static int testFinnalyBlock() throws Exception{
    int a=5,b=10;
    int sum=0;
    try{
        sum = a+b;
        System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
    }

   catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("In Catch");
        return 1; 
   }finally{
        sum = a+30;  
    }
    return sum;
}
```