# Java try..catch & finally

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have following code :

```
public class test3    
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        System.out.println("In main");
        System.out.println(new Demo(0).devide());    
    }
}
class Demo
{
    int x;
    Demo(int x)
    {
        this.x=x;
    }
    public int devide()
    {   
        try
        {
            return x/x;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            return 4;

        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("In finally");
            return 1;
        }    
    }
}
```

In above code I expect 4 as output but output generated is :

```
In main
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
In finally
1
```

so it returns `1`

Comment: this is exactly what has been asked in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification-in-java

Comment: Have a read through this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480258/finally-block-does-not-set-values-of-variable-in-java/18480305#18480305), it may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally is always invoked right before exiting the `try`/`catch` block, even if the `catch` returns. In effect, `return` in `finally` preceedes the return in `catch`, and the return in `catch` never takes place. See [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-1997/jw-02-hood.html) for details and explanation.

Basically, it boils down to the way it's translated to bytecode. Code in `finally` is treated as a "subprocedure", and at each exit point, right before leaving the `try`/`catch` block, a `jsr` jump is executed to the code in `finally`. As the subprocedure jump is not a real procedure call, `return` in `finally` inhibits the return from subprocedure to the point from which it was entered, and so the original `return` is never executed.

Rough translation of `divide()` to bytecode could look like this:

```
    aload_0
    getfield   // x
    dup
    idiv
    istore_1
    jsr        // to finally block
    iload_1
    ireturn

// catch
    bipush 4
    istore_1
    jsr        // to finally block
    iload_1
    ireturn

// finally
    astore_2   // save the return address
    bipush 1
    ireturn
    ret 2      // dead code
```

There we can see clearly **why** is the return in catch never executed.

Comment: _exiting the function_ is a misleading specification. Formally, `finally` is executed when exiting a `try`/`try-catch` block, which does not necessarily lie on a method's bounds.

Comment: @afk5min good point, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
finally
{

}
```

will be executed at last no matter what other code is executed before or not

So, at last it will return you `1`, which actually you didn't expect :)

Answer (score 2):

what happens is the following:

1. code reaches return 4;
2. value 4 is put on the return stack
3. code reaches return 1;
4. value 1 is put on the return stack
5. method ends, top of the stack is returned (thus value 1) and value 4 is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

```
In above code I expect 4 as output but output generated is :
In main
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
In finally
1
```

**What did you expect?**

Finally block will always be executed unless JVM crashes or you call System.exit() before. Since you are returning 1 in finally block you will get 1 as the output.

Answer (score 1):

As per *JLS 14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally:*

> If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly because of a `throw` of a value `V`, then there is a choice:
>
> If the run-time type of `V` is assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any `catch` clause of the `try` statement, then the first (leftmost) such `catch` clause is selected. The value `V` is assigned to the parameter of the selected `catch` clause, and the Block of that `catch` clause is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
> **If the `catch` block completes normally, then the `finally` block is executed.**

Answer (score 1):

`finally` block is always exectued, ALWAYS. Well maybe if you call `System.exit(0)` in the `try` it wouldn't be. But in other situations it is - no matter how the `try` / `catch` did exit (normally or abruptly).

The return value of `finally` (if you specify it) OVERWRITES the return from try/catch. Same goes for exceptions - the ones from try/catch get discarded, if finally throws its own exception.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `4` is also add to `stack` but after finally runs this will  return `1`. So that you can see only 1 since 1 is the top element of the stack.

Check this out

```
 try
    {
        return x/x;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        x=4;
        return x++;


    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("In finally");
        return x;
    }
```

What you can see

```
    In main
    java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    In finally
    5
```

now you can realize both catch and finally return the value, but we can see the top element in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Finally block is executed if your program execution control is entered into the try block.No mater whether try block will execute without any exception or any exception or in try block you are using return statement JVM will always execute finally block before terminating your program.
Ex:

```
 public class test3    
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        System.out.println("In main");
        System.out.println(new Demo(10).devide());    
    }
}
class Demo
{
    int x;
    Demo(int x)
    {
        this.x=x;
    }
    public int devide()
    {   
        try
        {
            return x/x;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            return 4;

        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("In finally");
            return 1;
        }    
    }
}
```

Above pgm will execute without any exception but still finally block will execute.