# Build dynamic navigation with list headers (coldfusion & cfscript)

Tags: coldfusion, menu, cfml

For a project im building a navigation. The table is like this

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [id]
    ,[title]
    ,[action]
    ,[listOrder]
    ,[fk_parentId]
FROM [portfolio].[dbo].[menu]
```

Where Fk_parentId refers to a id... to build up a menu with levels. Listorder contains a number

Now i want my navigation to output like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
       <li class="nav-header active">List header</li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
       <li class="nav-header">Another list header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

so the nav headers must be detected as a nav header and menu items as child. For now i have this code

```
public void function main(struct rc) {

    queryService = new query(); 
    queryService.setDatasource("portfolio"); 
    result = queryService.execute(sql="SELECT * FROM menu ORDER by listOrder"); 


    // result
    GetMenuData = result.getResult(); 


    // Loopen over result
    writeOutput("<ul class='nav nav-list>'");
    for (i = 1; i LTE GetMenuData.RecordCount; i = (i + 1))
    {

        // Output
        WriteOutput(
        "<li><a href='"& GetMenuData[ "action" ][ i ] & "'>" & GetMenuData[ "title" ][ i ] & "</a></li>"
        );

    }
    writeOutput("</ul>'");

}
```

this results:

```
    <ul class='nav nav-list>'
        <li><a href='alk.profile'>PROFILE</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>List header</a></li>
        <li><a href='main.'>home</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Another List header</a></li>
        <li><a href='alh.settings'>settings</a></li>
        <li><a href='main.library'>librarY</a></li>
        <li><a href='help.main'>Help</a></li>
        <li><a href='main.applications'>applications</a></li>
    </ul>'
```

How can I add class header to a "header" `<li>` like listheader, another list header?

How can i dynamicly add the divider between settings and help?

```
title                   action              listOrder   fk_parentId
Another List header     NULL                20          NULL
PROFILE                 alk.profile         5           539BB1A4-5AB5-4059-93AD-17DD8EABAF60
Help                    help.main           40          NULL
settings                alh.settings        20          539BB1A4-5AB5-4059-93AD-17DD8EABAF60
applications            main.applications   50          C5EFAE69-FD2A-4B35-A613-B8D429091A8F
List header             NULL                10          NULL
home                    main.               20          C5EFAE69-FD2A-4B35-A613-B8D429091A8F
librarY                 main.library        30          C5EFAE69-FD2A-4B35-A613-B8D429091A8F
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for cfoutput.  It has a group attribute that will probably make this easier.

Comment: FYI @r2get http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow - you do realise that all of your text is still visible just by seeing the log of edits right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see how you specify active from what you posted, but the following at least would result in the function returning the list with header classes.

```
public string function main(struct rc) {

    // Set up the return string
    var strReturn = '<ul class="nav nav-list">';

    // Set up the query
    var queryService = new Query(
        datasource='portfolio'
    ); 

    // Execute and get result, specifying field names
    var GetMenuData = queryService.execute(sql='
        SELECT 
            id,
            action,
            title,
            fk_parentId
        FROM menu
        ORDER by listOrder ASC
    ').getResult();

    // Loop over result
    for (var i = 1; i <= GetMenuData.RecordCount; i++) {

        // For this result, what classes are needed?
        var strClasses = '';

        // Header class
        if (
            Len(GetMenuData['fk_parentId'][ i ]) == 0 // Null / len 0 parent == header
        ) {
            strClasses = ListAppend(strClasses,'nav-header',' ');
        }

        // Add in some logic here for 'active' later on probably a good idea?
        // strClasses = ListAppend(strClasses,'active',' ') if id == active id? May need adjustment to query for parent

        if (
            Len(strClasses) > 0
        ) {
            strClasses  = ' class="'&strClasses&'"';
        }

        // Output list item
        strReturn &= '<li'&strClasses&'>';

            // Add href if needed
            if (
                Len(GetMenuData['action'][ i ]) > 0
            ) {
                strReturn &= '<a href="'&GetMenuData['action'][ i ]&'">';
            }

            strReturn &= GetMenuData['title'][ i ];

            if (
                Len(GetMenuData['action'][ i ]) > 0
            ) {
                strReturn &= '</a>';
            }

        // Close off the list item
        strReturn &= '</li>';
    }

    // End the return string
    strReturn &= '</ul>';

    // And return it
    return strReturn;
}
```

A few notes on the changes

- Changed function to have return type "string" instead of "void" and modified it so it returns a string instead of directly writing.  This in general allows more control over where precisely the list would be output.
- Added scoping for all variables invoked within the function (using 'var' keyword).  Please note that the below example will only work in CF9/railo.  If using a previous version then the var definitions need to be at top of the function, if unsure just ask
- Left a space to indicate where you would add in logic for flagging "active"
- Used `i++` in place of `i = (i + 1)` (see [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) for some info for what that does)
- Used `strReturn &= ...` to add to string, functionally equivilant to `strReturn = strReturn & ....`

Comment: For some reason it returns nothing ? bUT the query works though

Comment: Instead of just doing `main()` you'll need to do `WriteOutput(main());` or `<cfoutput>#main()#</cfoutput>` (for example) - just means this function generates the string in a way that is then usable elsewhere instead of outputting direct to the output buffer :)