# switch without break and i++ vs ++i

Tags: c, switch-statement

i dont understand why those two,have different output

there are two simple c programms

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i<3; i++)
            {
              switch (i++)
              {
               case 0:
               {
                 printf("zero");
               }
               case 1:
               {
                printf("one");
               }

               case 2:
               {
               printf("two");
               break;
               }

              default:
               {               
                printf("end");
               }                
        }
     }
}
```

this give this output:zero one two two

in this case after switch when the value from variable i change 0 to 1?

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i<3; i++)
     {
         switch (++i)
         {
            case 0:
            {
                printf("zero");
            }
            case 1:
            {
                printf("one");
            }

            case 2:
            {
                printf("two");
                break;
            }

            default:
            {             
                printf("end");
            }   

        }
     }
}
```

this give this output:one two end

Comment: Grab paper and pencil. Even better, a debugger. Use your 1. C book, 2. brain.

Comment: `i++` returns `i` before `1` is added. `++i` returns `i` after `1` is added. I'm prettu sure I've seen this question more than once on SO and google

Comment: Try printing out `i` at the beginning and end of each loop, and read up on the difference between `i++` and `++i` (plenty of postings on this site).

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
switch (i++)
     {
     }
```

is the same as:

```
int j=i;
i++;
switch (j)
    {
    }
```

while

```
switch (++i)
     {
     }
```

is the same as:

```
i++;
switch (i)
    {
    }
```

Comment: logically, not necessarily by compiler semantics... if anyone wants to complain

Comment: Really? With post-increment, all the case blocks are executed, and only then is i incremented?

Comment: Not exactly. For the postfix, the value is incremented before the code inside the braces gets executed. I still upvoted though. Edit: ninja'd.

Comment: Not exactly?! Not in any way at all. Save your voting until the answer is accurate. This is very badly misleading.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, pretty frustrating to have an answer that is misleading and not really correct get the votes... but this is the first time that it has ever worked out in my favor.

Comment: Well done for editing the answer and removing the offending part.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you have switch(i++) this means that the program will add 1 to i after it has finished the switch case and the other program has ++i meaning that the program will add 1 before going into the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

Using `i++` compared to `++i` is called postfix and prefix increment. The second case, `i` is given but incremented by 1 before going through the `switch`. Also, `case 3:` will occur because of this but since it doesn't exist `default` will occur on the final step of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `i` has the value `0`. Then

- `i++` evaluates to `0`. This is the post-increment operator.
- `++i` evaluates to `1`. This is the pre-increment operator.

And the value of `i` is incremented by `1` in both cases.

The difference between post-increment and pre-increment operators is clearly explained in your text book.

Oh, I should also say that your `main` function is declared incorrectly. It should be `int main(void)`.

You'd probably find the output of your programs easier to understand if you added in the missing `break` statements.