# What does operations in conditions means?

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements

I searched all over the internet to know what does this means :

```
while(i++)
```

I've seen a lot of code similar at this. 
What does the incrementation return to the condition of the while loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `i++` does two things. It evaluates to the current value of the variable `i`, and it then increments the stored value by one. So, if `i` is equal to `-1`, then in the case of `while(i++)`, `i++` evaluates to `-1`, which (being nonzero) is true, increments `i` to `0`, the the loop body is executed, and on the next iteration, `i++` evaluates to zero and increments `i` to `1`, and zero being false, the `while` finishes and execution proceeds beyond it.

Comment: Thank you !
And can you tell me what does the assignation ? ex : `while(a = b)`
My first guess is that it returns the value of b ... Well, I think t could only be that ..

Comment: @MalikFassi While(a=b) just assigns values of `b` to `a`.

Comment: `while(a=b)` assigns the value of `b` to `a`, and evaluates to that value. This is almost always an error... What's usually meant is `while(a==b)`, which evaluates to true as long as `a` and `b` have the same value.

Comment: @MalikFassi If in case you want to compare try `while (a == b)`

Answer (score 1):

The incrementation doesn't return anything to while loop condition.The value of the variable `i` is first checked to be true a and then it is incremented.

True means anything not equal to `0`.

Comment: So, the use of i++ to only increment is theoretically false ? As the evaluation is in excess.

Comment: it returns.. it just returns the previous value

Comment: @xaxxon OP just intended that this will return the incremented value and I answered according to that :) ... incrementation indeed is done after the condition is evaluated so , its not incrementation which returns :)

Answer (score 1):

In `while( i++ )`,value of `i` is evaluated as condition of `while`, after which `i` is incremented by `1`. This is called as **post increment** in *C* which has side-effect.

*Example,*

```
i = 1;
while( i++ )    // same as while( i ), 
                // side-effect is `i` incremented by 1 after this 
                // now i is 2
```

Refer, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/) for more information on increment operators.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code:

```
  #include"stdio.h"                                                                                                                                                          

  int main()
  {
      int i = -3;
      while(i++)
          printf("NUM I IS: %d\n",i);
      i = -3;
      printf("\n");
      while(++i)
         printf("NUM I IS: %d\n",i);
      return 0;
  }
```

the result is:

```
NUM I IS: -2
NUM I IS: -1
NUM I IS: 0

NUM I IS: -2
NUM I IS: -1
```

See, the second loop run only twice but first loop run 3th.

So

```
while(i++)
```

==>

```
while(i)
{
    i = i +1;
    ...
}
```

And

```
while(++i)
```

==>

```
while( i = i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`WHILE` loop understands only two things i.e. `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

`TRUE`=any value other than 0

`FALSE`=0

If the condition is true, the loop will run otherwise, it will get terminated.

In your case, you say `WHILE(i++)` that means you will keep incrementing the value of i & loop will go on until you get a `0`

example:

```
i= -2;
WHILE(i++)
{
condition
}
```

In first loop, value of i will be `-2` which is true. Condition will be executed & then i will be incremented. Thus, value of i now becomes`-2+1 = -1`

In second loop, value of i will be `-1` which is true. Condition will be executed & then i will be incremented. Thus, value of i now becomes `-1+1 = 0`

In third loop, value of i will be `0` which is false. Thus loop gets terminated.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, edited