# Why this below program is going for infinite loop?

Tags: c++, recursion, decrement

When I excuted this belo program, it is printing `5` inifnitely. Why?
Is it because the decrement is not happening or before decrement happens function call is happening?

I have tried the alternate way making `fun(--n)`, it gave me correct answer. But why it is not working for `fun(n--)`?

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if(!n)
    {
        cout << n << " " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << n << " "<<endl;
        fun(n--);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    fun(n);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++? This isn't C, just C++.

Comment: Because `n--` returns `5`.

Comment: Because you use the post decrement operator, it gives value 5 to fun and again and again... and after the function call n is decremented. Nice receipt for a stack overflow though.

Comment: I would call this infinite recursion by the way.

Comment: Although it has nothing to do with the problem, I'd also move the line `cout << n << " " <<endl;` before the `if`, as this makes the code simpler and doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `foo( n-- )` will return `n` and then decrement `n` by one (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1e3921c.aspx)), hence returning 5, 5, 5, ... repeated. You need to do **one** of the following:

```
foo( --n ); // or,
foo( n - 1 );
```

... and thus your code should look like this:

```
void fun( int n ) {
  if( !n ) {
    cout << n << " " << endl;
  } else {
    cout << n << " "<< endl;

    n--;
    fun( n );
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  int n = 5;

  fun( n );
  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

**Aside:** It's good practice to not include any increment or decrement operations within another expression. Had you of done the following it would of been ok:

```
n--;
foo( n );
```

... it can lead to confusion as a client (and even as the programmer) if you begin incrementing and decrementing within expressions. Consider this as another example where doing so is a *bad* idea:

```
if ( ( condition_1 == true ) && ( i++ == val ) )
```

... if the first condition is `false` it will never reach the second condition and hence not increment `i`.

Answer (score 7):

you need to do `foo(--n)` and not `foo(n--)`

- --n will decrement the value of n, and then send the decremented value
- n-- will decrement the value of n, but send the pre-decremented
  value.

so when you do `foo(n--)` you decement the value of n, but send to the `foo` function the n bofore decrementing. as you can guess that will go forever

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if(!n)
    {
        cout << n << " " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << n << " "<<endl;
        fun(--n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    fun(n);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

to learn more on the difference between `n--` and `--n` read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: It does not decrement n *after* the function has ended. its like `auto tmp = n; --n; fun(tmp);` and not like `fun(n); --n;`

Answer (score 3):

Because `fun(n--);` means call`fun` with value `n` and *then* decrement `n`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `n--` returns `n` *before* decrementing its value. Since you are calling your function that way, `n` always comes with the same value.
You could write `func(n--)` that way :

```
int temp = n;
n = n - 1;
func(temp);
```

Comment: It does not decrement n after the function has ended, but n-- returns the value n had before the increment was done. its like `auto tmp = n; --n; fun(tmp);` and not like `fun(n); --n;`

Comment: I see, this does make sense. I'll modify my answer accordingly. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Use `fun(--n)` instead of `fun(n--)`

The reason this happens this way is because `n--` decrements after the function has been run returning 5 repeatedly while `--n` decrements before.

Comment: @hetepeperfan Will annotate.

Comment: Quite obvious as it really is stated in the question that it does work. However, this answer does not say why.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if(!n)
    {
        cout << n << " " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << n << " "<<endl;
        fun(--n);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP already stated in his question that he knows that this works. He wanted to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your supplying the same value to fun() as was supplied in previous call.