# Simultaneous minimum and maximum

Tags: c++, algorithm, max, minimum

I've tried to implement an algorithm that would search for both minimum and maximum elements in  a given array, and used the ideas from Cormen's *Introduction to Algorithms*. My code compiles and starts working, outputs the generated random array and then does nothing for a really long time.
Why could that be?

The code is this:

```
// fast min and max --cormen exercise 1.cpp: entry point
//implemented from a verbal description in cormen's book, p 243

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct min_and_max
{
    int min, max;
};


min_and_max find_min_and_max(std::vector<int>& A)
{
    int n = A.size();
    int min, max;
    if (n%2 == 1)
        min = max = A[0];
    if (n%2 == 0)
        if (A[0] < A[1])
        {
            min = A[0];
            max = A[1];
        }
        else
        {
            min = A[1];
            max = A[0];
        }
    for(int i = 2; i < A.size(); (i + 2))
    {
        if (A[i] < A[i+1])
        {
            if (min > A[i])
                min = A[i];
            if (max < A[i+1])
                max = A[i+1];
        }
        else
        {
            if (min > A[i+1])
                min = A[i+1];
            if (max < A[i])
                max = A[i];
        }
    }
    min_and_max result;
    result.min = min;
    result.max = max;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    std::vector<int> A(10);
    for (auto i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        {
            A[i] = rand() % 1000;
            std::cout << A[i] << " ";           
        }
    std::cout << std::endl; //IT GOES AS FAR AS THIS
    std::cout << "The array has been analyzed; its' minimum is " << find_min_and_max(A).min << "and its' maximum is " << find_min_and_max(A).max << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you can use `std:pair<int, int>` to store both min and max values, instead of creating your own pair, also you can make `typedef pair<int, int> min_and_max`

Comment: Now the code runs properly, I can wonder about that: I have used `std::pair` in a previous version of this code, and then I somehow got the impression that a `struct` is faster. Is it really?

Comment: Incidentally, why are you making your algorithm this complicated? What's wrong with the [naive implementation](http://pastebin.com/nHPpzWNi)?

Comment: @Chiffa: `std::pair` is a struct almost identical to the one you used; also, the time used by your function is dominated by the loop looking for min/max, a difference in the return type is going to be negligible anyway.

Comment: Nothing, I guess. My idea was to write code that'd implement an algorithm's logic clearly - which, I hope, it does. It could probably be rewritten and simplified, but that's for tomorrow :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia, well, then I'd fall back to trusting the STL when in doubt.

Comment: it isn't it enough with a loop? `int maxval = INT_MIN; int minval = INT_MAX; for (auto& i : A ) { maxval = std::max( maxval, i ); minval = std::min( minval, i ); }`

Comment: Your struct is same as `std::pair` but with better member names.

Comment: It depends on the implementation, but basically it should be a template for a struct, check this implementation for [example](http://cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/stl__pair_8h-source.html)

Comment: In case you didn't know, there is a standard library algorithm for this called [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

Comment: Your problem is solved, but you still have an error. Try testing with `{1,9,2,8,3}`.

Comment: Tried it, yes, it outputs a wrong maximum. Could you please give a hint about the error?

Comment: Also, how did you come up with this input in the first place?

Comment: Look at the `for` loop and its limits, along with the code in the loop. That's what I did when I noticed the bug, then I worked backwards to create a test case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 for(int i = 2; i < A.size(); (i + 2))
```

`i + 2` won't change the value of `i`, you need to use `i += 2`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't really know how to write this increment properly.

Comment: Normally we use i++ which compiler interprets as 2 things return i and also increment it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Comment: @Nishant `i++` is used when you want to increment it by 1 and it would better be `++i`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies here:

```
for(int i = 2; i < A.size(); (i + 2))
```

You never actually increment `i`, thus causing an infinite loop.

change it to:

```
for(int i = 2; i < A.size(); i+=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the given answers, if you're using c++11 you can simplify your algorithm using [lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) and the `std::for_each` function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() { 
    int array[] = { -8, 8, 0, 9, 5, -3, 4, 6, -1, 15, 31 };
    int min, max;
    // User std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), ...) for either vector or list
    std::for_each(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [&min, &max](int elem) { 
        max = std::max(max, elem);
        min = std::min(min, elem);
    });
    std::cout << min << ", " << max << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And maybe it could be even simpler

**Update:** As [@Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445976/blastfurnace) pointed out, the `std::minmax_element` function could be used to further reduce the code needed for searching both the min and max element, yielding this shorter version:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> values = { -8, 8, 0, 9, 5, -3, 4, 6, -1, 15, 31 };
    auto minAndMax = std::minmax_element(values.begin(), values.end());
    std::cout << *minAndMax.first << ", " << *minAndMax.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*Is important to note that everything done in this answer, besides being OT, is for the sake of learning, to give the OP alternatives to improve his (or her) work and help other users that could have the same requirement.*

Comment: If you are using `C++11` it might make more sense to just use [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Comment: As I, personally, like lambdas, I would probably use them. As for the `std::minmax_element` it deals with several equivalent elements in a manner I'm not sure I need for this particular code.

Comment: @Chiffa: I also think lambdas are fantastic but `std::minmax_element` performs a minimum number of comparisons, it's correct, and it's library code I don't have to reinvent.

Comment: About the update -- this is really educational, and I'll be steadily improving my solution.

Answer (score 0):

In any case the algorithm is incorrect because the vector can have the size equal to 0. In this case 1) you try to access alements that are not exist and 2) you return undefined values from the function. The more correct approach is to return indexes of the minimum and maximum elements and in the case if the vector is empty return a pair of A.size().